# How to set interface conditions for optical waveguide in NDEigensystem?

Tags: differential-equations, physics, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, discontinuity

I have been working on waveguide mode analysis using FEM in *Mathematica* for a week, but I haven't succeeded until now.

The optical fiber-like waveguide is featured with different refractive index in core and in clad, and the interface between the core and the clad should have the boundary condition of $D_⊥$ (the normal component of $\mathbf{D}$) and $\mathbf{E}_∥$ (the tangential component of $\mathbf{E}$) are continuous. But I don't know how to express this kind of boundary condition in Mma. I think this is of course different in Neumann, Dirichlet and Robin conditions.

The physical model is described below.

For Helmholtz equation for optical waveguide:

$$\nabla ^2 E(x,y,z)+\epsilon (\frac{2 \pi} {\lambda})^2  E(x, y, z)=0$$

Assuming that 
$$E(x,y,z)=E(x,y) e^{i \beta z}$$

We have

$$\nabla ^2 E(x,y)+\epsilon \left(\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }\right)^2- \beta^2 E(x,y) = 0$$

The $\beta$ in this equation is to be solved and $\beta ^2$ can be considered as the eigen value of this eigen equation

$$\nabla ^2 E(x,y)+\epsilon \left(\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }\right)^2 = \beta^2 E(x,y)$$

$\epsilon$ is different for core and cladding, i.e. , $\epsilon_\text{core}$ and $\epsilon_\text{clad}$, respectively.

The boundary conditions at the interface should be : (1) the tangential component of the $\mathbf{E}$, i.e. $\mathbf{E}_∥$, is continuous. (2) the normal component of the $\mathbf{D}$, i.e. $D_⊥$, is continuous, in which $\mathbf{D}=\epsilon \mathbf{E}$.  In the cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$, the boundary conditions at interface should be, $E_z$ and $E_\theta$ is continuous, and $D_r$ is continuous.

**These conditions are my main concern when using FEM for the analysis of the eigenmode.** Although they can be formulated easily in some special cases such as in rectangular or circular waveguide, but I'd like to try a more general form.

Here is my unsuccessful try.( Mma 12.0, Win 10)

To make the mesh points on the boundary, it can be used like this,

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`

r = 0.8;
outerCirclePoints = 
    With[{r = 2.}, 
      Table[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ]}, {θ, Range[0, 2 π, 0.05 π] // Most}]]; (* the outer circle  *)
innerCirclePoints = 
    With[{r = r}, 
      Table[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ]}, {θ, Range[0, 2 π, 0.08 π] // Most}]]; (* the inner circle *)

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
      "Coordinates" -> Join[outerCirclePoints, innerCirclePoints], 
      "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[
            Riffle[Range[Length@outerCirclePoints], 
                RotateLeft[Range[Length@outerCirclePoints], 1]] // 
              Partition[#, 2] &], 
          LineElement[
            Riffle[Range[Length@outerCirclePoints + 1, 
                  Length@Join[outerCirclePoints, innerCirclePoints]], 
                RotateLeft[
                  Range[Length@outerCirclePoints + 1, 
                   Length@Join[outerCirclePoints,innerCirclePoints]],1]] //Partition[#,2] &]}];                                                     
    mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
{bmesh["Wireframe"], mesh["Wireframe"]}
 (* generate the boundary and element mesh, to make the mesh points \
on the outer and inner circles   *)

glass = 1.45^2; air = 1.; k0 = (2 π)/1.55;
ϵ[x_, y_] := If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, glass, air]

helm = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∇\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(u[x,y]\)\) + ϵ[x, y]*k0^2*u[x, y];
boundary = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., True];

(*region=ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2≤2.^2,{x,y}];*)

{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{helm, boundary}, u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 1,Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> {"FEAST","Interval" -> {k0^2, glass* k0^2}}}];
vals

 Table[Plot3D[funs[[i]], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> vals[[i]]], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

Although the profile in the figure seems right, but the eigenvalue is not right, since I can check it using analytical solutions.

---

**Edit 1**

I notice their is a very closely related post [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jU10.jpg), where PML is employed. However, there are some bug there, and it couldnot properly run.

Are there some more examples? Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit 2:**

For analytical solution, I have to mention that it can be obtained by solving a transdental equation shown in the figure for a circular waveguide. The derivation of this equation can be found in papers, for example, [https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-12-6-1025](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb6jr.jpg).

In addition, I can check the FEM results with other FEM tools like COMSOL.

---

**Edit 3**

I'm thankful to user21 for his kindness and patience. In this post, I will first give more information on the analytical solution, then I would present more clearly what I want to do with FEM.

Since there are too many equations, I'd like to post the revelant contents from textbooks (the appendix of “Photonics”, written by A. Yariv) about the analytical approch to the eigenmodes of optical fibers. I have underlined the most important equations in the pictures to make these stuffs to be understand more easily.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Therefore, for circular optical fibers, I just need to solve the transcedental equation of (B-11), that was shown in the figure in my original post.

Since FEM is a more general way to cope with eigensystems with diverse operators and boundary conditions in arbitrary calculation region, now I'd like to use the FEM in mathematica to get the eigenvalue of $\beta ^2$ of $\nabla ^2 E(x,y)+\epsilon \left(\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }\right)^2 = \beta^2 E(x,y)$, corresponding to the equation (A-7) underlined. Note that the eigenvalue is the square of the transcedental equation root in (B-11) underlined.

The codes in the newest post by user21 improves a lot compared in my original one, but I think it it still not right, since the calcutation result from COMSOL is exactly equal to the analytical solution.

---

**Edit 4:**

The following is the code for analytical solution.

```
λ = 1.55; ρ = 0.8; (* fiber core radius*)
ncore = 1.45;(*fiber core index*)
nclad = 1;(*fiber cladding index*) 
s = 1;(*β for Subscript[HE, sm] or Subscript[EH, sm] mode*)

k = (2 π)/λ;  
V = k ρ (ncore^2 - nclad^2)^(1/2); (*Print["V=",V];*)
U = ρ (k^2 ncore^2 - β^2)^(1/2); W = ρ (-k^2 nclad^2 + β^2)^(1/2);

Subscript[L, 1] = D[BesselJ[s, y], y]/(y BesselJ[s, y]) + 
       D[BesselK[s, z], z]/(z BesselK[s, z]); 
Subscript[L, 2] = D[BesselJ[s, y], y]/(y BesselJ[s, y]) + 
       (nclad^2/ncore^2) (D[BesselK[s, z], z]/(z BesselK[s, z])); 

lft = Subscript[L, 1 ] Subscript[L, 2] /. {y -> U, z -> W};
rght = ((s β)/(k ncore))^2 (V/(U W))^4;
bv = FindRoot[
   lft == rght, {β, 
    Boole[V <= 2.405]*(k nclad + 10^-10) + 
     Boole[V > 2.405]*(k ncore - 10^-10), k nclad + 10^-10, 
    k ncore - 10^-10}];
```

---

**Edit 5**

Actually, some of the FEM model for fiber eigenmode analysis uses this expression to calculate the eigenfrequency of the modes. I'm sorry that I cann't understand this.

$\omega^2=\frac{\int\left[(\nabla\times H)^*{\varepsilon}(\nabla \times H)+\rho (\nabla \times H)^*(\nabla \times H)\right]\text{dx}\text{dy}}{\int \text{dxdy}H\mu H^*}$

---

I'm not sure it is an answer. But I'll post it here and waiting for elegant Mathematica codes.

---

All the above answers are very helpful. However, I'm afraid none of them is correct.

Here I find something that may be useful on the github. I hope this can work as a hint for elegant Mma codes.

I copied this theory part from [here](https://github.com/ibegleris/WaFEl/blob/master/Dispersion_analysis.ipynb). It also included python codes.

### I think models like this would be very helpful for non-expert users like me, and I don't know whether it is possible to include such a model in Mathematica, like in COMSOL. Actually, this is the real motivation for this question.

Theory
(taken from the fenics book)

We are solving the Helmholtz equation:

$$\nabla \times \frac{1}{\mu_r}\nabla \times \boldsymbol{E} - k_0^2 \epsilon_r \boldsymbol{E}=0,$$ with the boundary condition of electric mirrors. $$k_0 = \frac{2\pi f_0}{c_0}$$

$$\epsilon_r = (n+\mathrm{i}k)^2$$

The functional is: $$F(\boldsymbol{E}) = \frac{1}{2} \int_\Omega \left[\frac{1}{\mu_r} \left(\nabla \times \boldsymbol{E}\right)\cdot \left(\nabla \times \boldsymbol{E}\right) - k^2_0 \epsilon_r \boldsymbol{E}\boldsymbol{E}\right]dx$$

In order to find it the vector is split in to the transverse and axial components.

$$\nabla = \nabla_t + \nabla_z,$$
with $$\nabla_t = \hat{e_x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \hat{e_y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$ and $$\nabla_z = \hat{e_z}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$ We also assume that the electric field can be split like: $$\boldsymbol{E}(x,y,z) = \left[E_t(x,y) + \hat{e_z} E_z(x,y) \right] e^{-\beta z}$$ where $\beta$ is the complex propagation constant, $$\boldsymbol{E}_t = \hat{e_x} E_x + \hat{e_y} E_y$$ and $$ \boldsymbol{E}_{axial} = \hat{e_z} E_z$$

By splitting the $\nabla$ and by substituting the above for the electric field the functional becomes: $$ F_{\beta}(\boldsymbol{E}) =  \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\mu_r} \left(\nabla_t \times \boldsymbol{E}_{t,\beta}\right) \cdot \left(\nabla_t \times \boldsymbol{E}_{t,\beta}\right) -k^2_0 \epsilon_r E_{t,\beta}E_{t,\beta} \\ + \beta^2 \left[\frac{1}{\mu_r} \left(\nabla_t E_z+\beta E_{t,\gamma}\right)\left(\nabla_t E_z+\beta E_{t,\gamma}\right) - k^2_0 \epsilon_r E_z E_z dx \right]$$

Since the functional is built now the electric field components need to be discetized in order to be calculated. The axial component can be discretised by nodal basis functions (Lagrandge) but the transverse need to be by two dimensional curl-conforming vector basis functions(Nedelec).

The electric field in the nedelec space is described by: $$E_{t} = \sum_{i=1}^{N_{N}} (e_t)_i N_i$$

and the axial in lagrange elements as:

$$E_z = \sum_{i=1}^{N_{L}} (e_z)_i L_i$$
Where $N_N$ and $N_L$ are the number of nedelec and lagrange elements respectively. $N_i$, $L_i$ are the basis functions and $e_t$, $e_z$ are the equivalent coefficients.

While the cuttoff method is easier to implement it only prety much finds the cuttoff wavenumber (shown in fenics book and in other papers). This is not what is of interest. I am interested in calculating the propagation constants $\beta$ and by extension the effective indices and the Electric field that they equate to.

The matrix eqution to be solved is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A_{tt}       &amp; 0 \\
0       &amp; 0 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
e_t \\
e_z      
\end{bmatrix} = -\beta^2
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{tt}       &amp; B_{tz} \\
B_{zt}       &amp; B_{zz} 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
e_t \\
e_z      
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $$A_{tt} = S_{tt} - k^2_0 T_{tt} = \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\mu_r} \left(\nabla_t \times N_i \right) \left(\nabla_t \times N_j \right)dx \\ - k^2_0 \int_{\omega} \epsilon_r N_i N_jdx$$

$$B_{zz} = S_{zz} - k^2_0 T_{zz} = \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\mu_r} \left(\nabla_t L_i \right) \left(\nabla_t L_j \right)dx \\ - k^2_0 \int_{\omega} \epsilon_r L_i L_j dx$$
$$ B_{tt} = \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\mu_r} N_i \cdot  N_j dx$$$$ B_{tz} = \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\mu_r} N_i \cdot  \nabla_t L_j dx$$$$ B_{zt} = \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\mu_r} \nabla_t L_i \cdot  N_j dx$$

https://github.com/ibegleris/WaFEl/blob/master/Dispersion_analysis.ipynb

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94436/discussion-on-question-by-yulinlinyu-how-to-set-the-boundary-conditions-for-eige).

Answer (score 11):

There are three conditions when we want to get eigenfunctions in Cartesian coordinates, similar to eigenfunctions in cylindrical coordinates. The first is the correspondence of boundaries. The second is the azimuth number match, eg $l_1=l_2=0$.Third, the radius of the outer circle must meet the boundary condition. All three conditions are violated in the author’s code. I show how to find the eigenfunction with $\beta = 5.336$.

```
    << NDSolve`FEM`

r = 0.8; ne = 10; om = 0.0; kap = 1000;
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 2.0928^2, {x, y}]; f = 
 Function[{vertices, area}, 
  Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices]; 
   If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, area > 0.001, area > 0.01]]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MeshRefinementFunction -> f];


glass = 1.45; air = 1.; k0 = (2 \[Pi])/1.55; b = 5;
n[R_] := ( .5*(1 - Tanh[kap*(R - r)])*(glass^2 - air^2) + air^2)*k0^2

helm = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - (b^2 + n[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]])*
    u[x, y] + I*om*(x*D[u[x, y], y] - y*D[u[x, y], x]);
boundary = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];
{vals, funs} = 
    NDEigensystem[{helm, boundary}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   ne];

Sqrt[Re[vals] + b^2]

(* {5.01271, 5.01285, 5.03804, 5.03825, 4.92974, 4.92969, \
5.28019, 5.28066, 5.33615, 5.60683}*)
```

Here we can see that the 9-th eigenvalue is equal to 5.33615, which corresponds to the desired $\beta = 5.336$. Figure 1 shows the mesh and eigenfunction along with the cylinder bounding the fiberglass.

```
{Show[ mesh["Wireframe"], 
  ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == r^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue]], 
 Show[Plot3D[Re[funs[[9]]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotLabel -> Sqrt[vals[[9]] + b^2], Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue], 
  Graphics3D[{Gray, Opacity[.4], 
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1.}}, r]}]]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2 shows the remaining functions with $l\ne 0$ and desired eigenfunction with $l=0$
[image: Figure 2]

To isolate monotone solutions in  the clad with `l = 1`, we add to the Helmholtz operator `(b^2 + l^2/(x^2 + y^2))*u[x, y]` and choose eigenfunctions that fade out in the outer region what is achieved when `b = I*Sqrt[glass]*k0`. Figure 3 shows one of the eigenfunctions. In this case, the desired value $\beta = 5.336$ is achieved with increasing size of the clad. In fig. 4 shows the same eigenfunction with a 2-fold increase in the size of the region of integration.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
r = 0.8; ne = 10;  kap = 1000; l = 1;
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 2^2, {x, y}]; f = 
 Function[{vertices, area}, 
  Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices]; 
   If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, area > 0.001, area > 0.01]]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MeshRefinementFunction -> f];


glass = 1.45; air = 1.; k0 = (2 \[Pi])/1.55; b = I*Sqrt[glass]*k0;
n[R_] := ( .5*(1 - Tanh[kap*(R - r)])*(glass^2 - air^2) + air^2)*k0^2

helm = -Laplacian[
     u[x, y], {x, y}] - (b^2 + n[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + l^2/(x^2 + y^2))*
    u[x, y];
boundary = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];

{vals, funs} = 
    NDEigensystem[{helm, boundary}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   ne];

Sqrt[vals + b^2]


(*{0. + 4.93777 I, 0. + 5.29335 I, 0. + 5.29463 I, 
 0. + 3.9743 I, 0. + 3.97351 I, 0. + 3.51044 I, 0. + 3.50924 I, 
 0. + 3.23389 I, 0. + 2.86891 I, 0. + 2.86774 I}*)
{Show[ mesh["Wireframe"], 
  ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == r^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue]], 
 Show[Plot3D[Im[funs[[3]]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"\[Beta] = ", Im[Sqrt[vals[[3]] + b^2]]}], 
   Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue], 
  Graphics3D[{Gray, Opacity[.4], 
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1.}}, r]}]]}

Table[Plot3D[Im[funs[[i]]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> Sqrt[vals[[i]] + b^2], Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

[image: Figure 3]
[image: Figure 4]
And finally I give the best result that was obtained in this model with `l = 1`:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
r = 0.8; ne = 1; kap = 10000; l = 1;
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 5.3^2, {x, y}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{vertices, area}, 
     area > 0.0004 (1 + 9 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]];


glass = 1.45; air = 1.; k0 = (2 \[Pi])/1.55; b = I*Sqrt[glass]*k0*1.1;
n[R_] := ( .5*(1 - Tanh[kap*(R - r)])*(glass^2 - air^2) + air^2)*k0^2

helm = -Laplacian[
     u[x, y], {x, y}] - (b^2 + n[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + l^2/(x^2 + y^2))*
    u[x, y];
boundary = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];

{vals, funs} = 
    NDEigensystem[{helm, boundary}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   ne];


{Show[ mesh["Wireframe"], 
  ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == r^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue]], 
 Show[Plot3D[Im[funs[[1]]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"\[Beta] = ", Im[Sqrt[vals[[1]] + b^2]]}], 
   Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue], 
  Graphics3D[{Gray, Opacity[.4], 
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1.}}, r]}]]}
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Why was the Helmholtz equation and n[R] changed  so much? How can you figure them out?

Comment: @yulinlinyu Virtually nothing has changed. `b` is a calibration constant that is included in the definition of $\beta $.  `b` is used instead of option `Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> {"FEAST","Interval" -> {k0^2, glass* k0^2}}}`. `n[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]` practically  is the same as yours `\[Epsilon][x, y]*k0^2` .

Comment: It seems the `heml` in your codes are a bit different from that of mine. Any way, I'll check out your code after some modifications. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the `helm` in your codes, `n[R]=air^2 when R>r`, and `n[R]=air^2+glass^2 when R<r`.That is different from the origin post. And the eigenfucntions is not quite right, since the mode field of fiber is BesselK in the clad, and it is not oscillatory.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I changed the code and pictures. Now `n[R]=air^2` when `R>r`, and `n[R]=glass^2` when `R<r`.  As for oscillations, this is a border effect at $r=2$. There is no border at $r=2$ in your solution?

Comment: No, there should be no oscillations in the clad. You can see the analytical solution in expressions (B-7) and (B-9) in my post.

Comment: In addtion to the oscillatory behavior in the clad, the fundamental mode of optical fiber corresponding  to `l=1`. Is it possible to show this? In expression (A-7), the Helmholtz equation is `Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}]+（k^2-\beta ^2）u[x,y]=0`. Therefore, I'm just wondering why you use `b^2` in front of `k^2`, and how can you find the value  `2.0928`or `1.9615` in your former post? Thank you very much.

Comment: @yulinlinyu Read the tutorial: `An eigenvalue and eigenfunction pair {Subscript[\[Lambda], i],Subscript[u, i]} for the differential operator \[ScriptCapitalL] satisfy \[ScriptCapitalL][u[x,y,\[Ellipsis]]]==Subscript[\[Lambda], i] Subscript[u, i][x,y,\[Ellipsis]].` Therefore, if we make a replacement (calibration) $\lambda _i\rightarrow \lambda _0+\lambda _i$, and move $\lambda _0u[x,y]$ to the left side and denote $\lambda _0=b^2$, we get the equation that I used.

Comment: Nice solution. From your post, I guess you are an expert in electromagnetics or optical waveguides. There are two points I cannot understand in your solution. 1. What do you mean by `I*om*(x*D[u[x, y], y] - y*D[u[x, y], x])` in `helm`.？ Of course this term can be neglected since `om=0`. But I think you must have something in your mind , haven't you?

Comment: 2. Why is there a term `l^2/(x^2 + y^2))*u[x, y]` in `helm`?  In my opinion, this term will apear only in the cylindrical coordinate, and it  was **included** in the Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}] in x-y coordinates already. Why do you use them explicitly in `helm` again in x-y coordinates? Thank you very much.

Comment: @yulinlinyu Sorry, I edited the post, removed the `I*om` term, it came from quantum mechanics. The term `l^2/(x^2 + y^2))*u[x, y]` is also used to calibrate eigenvalues. This term is singled out specifically to make `NDEigensystem[]` search for eigenvalues around a given `l=1`.

Comment: This is a very clever solution.Will this term `l^2/(x^2 + y^2))*u[x, y]` bring some errors for eigenvalues? Since it is added manually, and isn't come from the equation. `l^2/(x^2 + y^2))` is not a constant like b^2, but contains variable x and y in it.

Comment: @yulinlinyu In fact, we do not break anything when we explicitly select the angular part of the operator with given $l$. After all, this part really exists. And we can always break it into two parts using explicitly one of them.

Comment: can you explain it more? I get lost here. In  eq（A-7）I post, there is no such term. I thought it came from the term of `d/d[fai]`. But all the first three terms equals to `Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}]`. I know you are right. In fact, I have tried to exclude this term, but the eigenvalue is far from the correct value although the eigenvector seems right.

Comment: I also try to use a larger clad in your codes, but the eigenvalue persists be about 5.30 or something like that. It is a little bit smaller than the exact value of 5.33. However, the COMSOL can get 5.33 exactly. Can you comment this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you've forgotten to add the minus back when calculating $\beta$ i.e. it should be `Sqrt[-(vals + b^2)]` rather than `Sqrt[vals + b^2]`. And, I'm afraid it's just impossible to obtain the correct result only with Helmholtz equation. Please see my answer below for more details.

Comment: @xzczd I have not forgotten, since  in my code `\[Beta] =  Im[Sqrt[vals[[1]] + b^2]]` and `vals[[1]] +b^2<0`. You can just take `\[Beta] =  Sqrt[-(vals[[1]] + b^2)]` :)

Comment: Oh… actually I mean the code in the first code block. (I didn't check the remaining blocks carefully… )

Comment: A great answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a complete answer but a few more things to think about:

Generate the mesh:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
glass = 1.45^2;
air = 1.;
k0 = (2 Pi)/1.55;
\[Epsilon][x_, y_] := 
 If[ElementMarker == 1, Evaluate[glass], Evaluate[air]]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Annulus[{0, 0}, {0.8, 2}], "RegionHoles" -> None,
    "RegionMarker" -> {{{0, 0}, 1}, {{3/2, 0}, 2}}(*,
   "MaxCellMeasure"\[Rule]0.0025*)];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Set up the equation and boundary condition only at the outer boundary (Using `True` will also make use of the internal boundary)

```
helm = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + \[Epsilon][x, y]*k0^2*u[x, y];
boundary = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 >= 2];
```

Note that there are more eigenvalues in the interval you request:

```
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{helm, boundary}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 3, 
  Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> {"FEAST", 
      "Interval" -> {k0^2, glass*k0^2}}}]

(* {{21.8177, 21.8179, 29.2875},... } *)
```

But you requested `NDEigensystem` to only return one.

Note there are also negative eigenvalues:

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{helm, boundary}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 40];
vals

{-2.09566, -2.10176, 2.30094, 2.30241, -2.74458, -2.74508, -3.84583, \
-3.85689, 4.79376, 5.27311, 5.27699, 7.27767, 7.2782, -8.27121, \
-8.27829, 9.51751, 9.51881, -11.3267, -11.3395, -11.6234, -11.6335, \
-11.6822, 13.2792, 13.6627, 13.6649, -14.3816, -14.3887, -19.6736, \
-19.6883, -20.4762, -20.4798, -20.9379, -20.9583, -21.1027, -21.1095, \
21.8177, 21.8179, -28.4373, -28.4643, 29.2875}
```

You could not catch those with the FEAST interval specified.

Last, I am not sure if you are looking for lambda or lambda^2:

```
vals^2

{4.39178, 4.41741, 5.29434, 5.30111, 7.5327, 7.53544, 14.7904, \
14.8756, 22.9802, 27.8057, 27.8467, 52.9645, 52.9722, 68.4129, \
68.5301, 90.5831, 90.6077, 128.295, 128.584, 135.102, 135.339, \
136.475, 176.338, 186.669, 186.73, 206.831, 207.035, 387.05, 387.627, \
419.275, 419.424, 438.397, 439.251, 445.322, 445.609, 476.013, \
476.022, 808.683, 810.215, 857.756}
```

The 27.8 value will get closer to 28 when you refine the mesh.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness and patience. But I'm afraid it is still problematic. Please see the new Edit 3 .

Comment: @yulinlinyu, what boundary conditions did you apply in COMSOL?

Comment: @yulinlinyu, what *exact* refractive index did you use?

Comment: @yulinlinyu, what eigenvalue do you expect?

Comment: @yulinlinyu, can you post the analytical solution as Mathematica code?

Comment: OK. Actually, the analytical solution is very easy. It is the root of the transcedental equation (B-11). I'll post the mma code very soon after dinner.

Comment: I have checked papers for eigenmode solving in waveguide. They didn't solve the Helmholtz equation directly. They used a very complicated model. If you need, I can provide the papers.

Comment: @yulinlinyu, why do you think that the different equation used in COMSOL should give the same result as the Helmholtz equation used here?

Comment: Physically, they should be the same, since the eigenmode of the same optical fiber has been well solved. In addtion, the result of COMSOL agrees well with the analytical solution shown in the post.

Comment: @yulinlinyu, I am not disputing that COMSOL gives a wrong result. I am saying that the Helmholtz equation may not be a good model for this problem. Check the Helmholtz equation setup with COMSOL and see if that also gives the results you expect.

Comment: OK，thank you all the same for your kindness and patience.

Comment: @yulinlinyu, when you are done, I am curious to hear what the result is.

Comment: @yulinlinyu, did you get a chance to test the helmholtz equation with COMSOL?

Comment: COMSOL has a model for solving fiber eigenmodes. it provides too little information on how it works. I can email you some papers on this issue if you are intested with papers on this issue. I know too little on the algorithm of FEM and I cannot understand well these papers.

Comment: @yulinlinyu, COMSOL certainly can solve a helmholtz equation. Try to do that. If the the result is the same as in Mathematica then you know that you need to work with a better model. If the result in COMSOL with the helmholtz equation is different then we need to track the difference down. I suspect that the COMSOL and Mathematica solution for the Helmholtz equation are very similar.

Comment: I think the result will be the same for solving the Helmholtz equation. But I'd  to figure out why it is not right to solve Helmholtz equation directly to get the fiber eigenmodes.

Comment: Please look at my new edit----Edit 5.

Answer (score 7):

Not a perfect answer, but I believe I've found the correct direction.

## Theory

First of all, I'd like to emphasize the following:

1. Helmholtz equation for electric field is deduced from Maxwell's equations in frequency domain **assuming permittivity $\epsilon$ is constant**.
2. Piecewise constant is not constant.

In other words, simply solving Helmholtz equation in the whole domain of definition won't produce the correct result, even if the piecewise constant is approximated with a smooth function. Linking the 2 sub-domain of definition with proper interface condition (as shown in the screenshot given by OP) is a possible solution, but that's just troublesome. A better approach is to turn to a more general equation that's valid even at the interface (in the sense of limit). Then which equation should we use? Well, I'm not an expert of electromagnetism, but I found the one mentioned in [*Full-vectorial mode calculations by finite difference method* by *C.L.Xu*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/331645) seems to be a possible choice.

I'll repeat the deduction in this post for completeness. Starting from Maxwell's equations in frequency domain

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E}=- j \omega \mu_0 \mathbf{H} \tag{1}$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{H}= j \omega n^2 \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} \tag{2}$$

Take the curl of $(1)$ and substitute it into $(2)$, we have

$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{E}- n^2 k^2 \mathbf{E}=0 \tag{3}$$

where $k=\omega/c$ and $c=1/\sqrt{\epsilon_0 \mu_0}$.

With the vector identity

$$ \nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \mathbf{A} \right) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}) - \nabla^{2}\mathbf{A} \tag{4}$$

$(3)$ becomes

$$\nabla^2 \mathbf{E}+n^2 k^2 \mathbf{E}=\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}) \tag{5}$$

Notice if $\epsilon$ is constant, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}$ will be $0$ based on Gauss's law, thus $(5)$ will simplify to Helmholtz equation, but of course we can't do this here.

Then let's eliminate $E_z$. The **transverse** components of $(5)$ are

$$\nabla_t^2\mathbf{E}_t+n^2 k^2 \mathbf{E}_t=\nabla_t(\nabla_t \cdot \mathbf{E}_t+\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z}) \tag{6}$$

where $\nabla_t=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$ and $\mathbf{E}_t=(E_x,E_y)$ in Cartesian coordinate.

Since **$n$ is $z$-invariant in waveguide** i.e. $\partial n/\partial z=0$, Gauss's law

$$\nabla \cdot( n^2 \mathbf{E})=0 \tag{7}$$

can be transformed to

$$\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z}=-\frac{1}{n^2} \nabla_t \cdot (n^2 \mathbf{E}_t) \tag{8}$$

Substitute $(8)$ and

$$\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)=\mathbf{E}(x,y)e^{-j \beta z} \tag{9}$$

into $(6)$, we have

$$\boxed{\nabla_t^2\mathbf{E}_t+n^2 k^2 \mathbf{E}_t - \nabla_t\left(\nabla_t \cdot \mathbf{E}_t -\frac{1}{n^2} \nabla_t \cdot \left(n^2 \mathbf{E}_t\right)\right) = \beta^2 \mathbf{E}_t} \tag{10}$$

The remaining work is just to solve the equation.

## `"FiniteElement"`-based Approach

It's straightforward to solve equation $(10)$ with the built-in `NDEigensystem`. First, code the equations:

```
lap = Laplacian[#, {x, y}] &;
grad = Grad[#, {x, y}] &;
div = Div[#, {x, y}] &;
elst = e[#][x, y] & /@ Range[2];

lhs = With[{n2 = n2[x, y]}, 
   lap@elst + (n2 k^2) elst - grad[div@elst - 1/n2 div[n2 elst]]];
```

Next step is to approximate the piecewise constant with a smooth function:

```
r = 8/10;
glass = (145/100)^2; air = 1;
k = (2 π)/155 100;
appro = With[{k = 100}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
n2 = (Function[{x, y}, #] &@(Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
       PiecewiseExpand@If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, glass, air] /. UnitStep -> appro))
```

Notice this step is necessary, or the solution won't converge to the desired result and you'll see the eigenvalue close to `29` again.

Finally, generate the mesh and solve for the eigenfunctions:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
outer = 2;
mesh = ToElementMesh[Annulus[{0, 0}, {r, outer}], "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01];
mesh["Wireframe"]

{val, vec} = 
   NDEigensystem[{lhs /. para /. {e[1] -> e1, e[2] -> e2}}, {e1, e2}, {x, y} ∈ mesh, 6, 
     Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> k^2 glass}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 13.5384 seconds, in a 8-core machine. *)
val
(* {19.8019, 19.8068, 20.1241, 21.7348, 28.351, 28.3528} *)

DensityPlot[#[[1]][x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50] &@vec[[-1]]
```

[image]

Still, the eigenvalue isn't `5.336^2 == 28.4729`, and the resulting graphic is slightly but apparently skrew, but this time we've at least been close to the analytic solution. Sadly I fail to improve the result further.

## FDM-based Approach

In the `"FiniteElement"`-based approach, the derivative of $\epsilon$ is calculated symbolically so a very dense grid is needed to capture the sudden variation of $\epsilon$, and this may be a reason for the inaccuracy of the result, so I decide to turn to FDM, with which the symbolic derivation is avoided naturally.

We first introduce 3 intermediate variables to avoid symbolic derivation:

```
r = .8;
glass = (1.45)^2; air = 1.;
k = (2 π)/1.55;
n2 = Function[{x, y}, #] &@(Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
     PiecewiseExpand@If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, glass, air]);
With[{n2 = n2[x, y]}, lhs = lap@elst + (n2 k^2) elst - grad@term[x, y];
  termrhs = div@elst - 1/n2 div@{termx[x, y], termy[x, y]};
  {termxrhs, termyrhs} = n2 elst];
```

Then discretize the left hand side (`lhs`) based on FDM. I'll use [`pdetoae`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871), and discretizing the system in Cartesian coordinate for simplicity:

```
difforder = 1; points = 400; L = 2; domain = {-L, L}; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];

n2[#, grid] & /@ grid // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

As we can see, the approximation for the waveguide isn't bad with the dense enough grid.

```
ptoafunc = pdetoae[Flatten[{e /@ {1, 2}, term, termx, termy}][x, y], {grid, grid}, 
   difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

ae = del /@ del@# & /@ ptoafunc@lhs; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {26.967, Null} *)
{aetermrhs, aetermxrhs, aetermyrhs} = 
   ptoafunc@{termrhs, termxrhs, termyrhs}; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {24.0939, Null} *)
vare = Outer[e[#][#2, #3] &, Range@2, del@grid, del@grid, 1] // Flatten;

Block[{term, termx, termy},
  Evaluate@ptoafunc@Through[{term, termx, termy}[x, y]] = {aetermrhs, aetermxrhs, 
    aetermyrhs};
  {barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[ae // Flatten, vare]; // AbsoluteTiming]
(* {58.6109, Null} *)
{val, vec} = 
   Eigensystem[marray, -6, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> k^2 glass}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {23.9645, Null}, in a 8-core machine. *)    
mat = ArrayReshape[#, {2, points - 2, points - 2}] & /@ vec;
Parallelize@
 MapThread[ArrayPlot[#[[1]], PlotLabel -> Sqrt@#2, PlotRange -> All, 
    ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] &, {mat, val}]
```

[image]

As we can see, the result is closer to `5.336`, but once again, I fail to improve the result further. Simply make the grid denser or make `L` larger won't help. Perhaps the automatic discretization by `pdetoae` is too naive in this case and a better difference scheme is necessary.

## Remark

1. `NDEigenSystem` won't work without the replacement `{e[1] -> e1, e[2] -> e2}`. (`e[1]` and `e[2]` causes the warning `NDEigensystem::baddep`.) I'm not sure about the reason.
2. `"FEAST"` method can't be used, otherwise the warning `Eigensystem::nosymh` pops up. I'm not sure about the reason.
3. The utilization of Gauss's law in the deduction of $(10)$ seems to be critical. Actually one can still eliminate $E_z$ with $(1)$ and $(2)$ only, but the deduced equation just can't converge to the desired result. I guess this might be related to the observation that numeric algorithm that doesn't obey Gauss's law can be inaccurate. (Check **Introduction** section of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782507002836?via%3Dihub) for more information. )
4. If you insists on solving the problem with Helmholtz equation with interface condition, notice the interface conditions in the question aren't sufficient. One still needs another 3 conditions for $\mathbf{H}$ i.e. the tangential component of $\mathbf{H}$ is continuous across the surface if there's no surface current present.
5. Dirichlet b.c.s are essentially set by `del@grid` in `vare`. Since the elements at the boundary of domain aren't included in `vare`, they will be treated as constant and moved to `barray` by `CoefficientArray`, which is equivalent to setting zero Dirichlet b.c.s.

Comment: I have not been able to follow the discussion, but I am curious how the correct weak formulation of these Helmholtz equations would look like. Actually, I expect the equation should read $\nabla \cdot \big( \varepsilon^{-1} \, \nabla E \big) + \lambda\, E = 0$, where $\varepsilon$ has a jump-type discontinuity along a spherical surface. This way, all the fuzz with virtual boundary conditions on an interior surface might become obsolete. One has only to take care that the stiffness matrix is assembled correctly. No?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I thought so, too, but this equation won't lead to the correct solution, and after playing with Maxwell's equations for quite a while, I noticed this seemingly reasonable equation is simply baseless…The continuity conditions for Maxwell equations are just not as simple as equation of heat conduction.

Comment: I see. Very interesting.

Comment: @xzczd Here you found a solution with `l = 0`. Now we need to find a solution with `l = 1` and with $\beta =5.336$.

Comment: The evaluation can be faster by searching for a fewer eigenvalues if you adopt the trick of shifting the eigenvalues shown by Alex.

Comment: @yulinlinyu I didn't use that technique because I thought I would find something interesting outside, but so long I don't, and I'm tired of waiting, so the shift is added now (in a better way). A FDM approach is also added and the result is slightly improved, see my update.