# 3D FEM Vector Potential

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, discontinuity, opencascade, axisymmetry

I am trying to reproduce an FEM result in a paper. Due to possible copyright I cannot show the result directly but fortunately there is a free link

[An Incomplete Gauge for 3D Nodal Finite Element Magnetostatics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3096485_An_incomplete_gauge_formulation_for_3D_nodal_finite-element_magnetostatics)

The important Figs. are 1-3. Basically the problem is quite simple. An iron cube 4x4x4cm sitting in a vertical 1Tesla field. Due to symmetry only 1/8 must be simulated using FEM. The air boundary of the 1/8th model is set at 10x10x10cm. Boundary conditions on the magnetic vector potential are imposed on the boundary faces to ensure the symmetry and also a field of 1T in the z-direction.

The basic equation to be solved is curl(v*curl(A)) = J. In this problem J (current density) = 0. The resultant matrix to be solved after discretizing is often ill-conditioned, but can be improved by applying a gauge (typically Coulomb div(A)=0), but with loss of accuracy. Coulomb gauging  results in a Poisson Equation: Div(Grad(A))=J, and when J=0 the Laplacian. Even with the ill-conditioning an ICCG solver can usually converge to a solution. Using the MVP for magnetostatics is not particularly computationally efficient and so reduced-total scalar solutions have been the preferred method for this type of problem for nearly 30 years. However that requires solving separate pde's in the different material regions and imposing interface constraints - but that is question for another time.

My code to solve the problem is shown, and uses hexahedron (brick) finite elements, as did the result in the paper.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

\[Mu]o = 4.0*\[Pi]*10^-7;
\[Mu]r = 1000.0;(*iron relative permeability*)

a = 0.02; (*iron cube length(s)*)

ironEdgeBricks = 
  4; (*integer number of brick elements along iron edge*)

airRegionScale = 
  5; (*integer scaling factor of air region to iron region*)

fluxDensity = 1.0; (*applied flux density in z direction*)

n = ironEdgeBricks*airRegionScale + 1; 
b = airRegionScale*a;
coordinates = 
 Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, 0, b, b/(n - 1)}, {y, 0, b, 
    b/(n - 1)}, {z, 0, b, b/(n - 1)}], 2]; incidents = 
 Flatten[Table[
   Block[{p1 = (j - 1)*n + i, p2 = j*n + i, p3 = p2 + 1, p4 = p1 + 1, 
     p5, p6, p7, p8},
    {p5, p6, p7, p8} = {p1, p2, p3, p4} + k*n*n;
    {p1, p2, p3, p4} += (k - 1)*n*n;
    {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8}], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, 
    n - 1}, {k, 1, n - 1}], 2];

mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[incidents]}, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], RegionPlot3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, a, a}]], 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Resulting Mesh]

Now to the solution

```
u = {ux[x, y, z], uy[x, y, z], 
  uz[x, y, z]}; (*vector potential components*)
\[Nu]1 = 
 If[x \[LessSlantEqual] a && y \[LessSlantEqual] a && 
   z \[LessSlantEqual] a, 1/(\[Mu]r*\[Mu]o), 
  1/\[Mu]o];(*permeability depending on iron cube in mesh*) 
\[CapitalGamma]d = {DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == 0, y == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == -fluxDensity*b/2, y == b], 
  DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == 0, x == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == fluxDensity*b/2, x == b], 
  DirichletCondition[uz[x, y, z] == 0, 
   y == b || y == 0 || x == 0 || x == b || z == 0 || z == b]};
\[CapitalGamma]n = {0, 0, 0};

op1 = Curl[\[Nu]1*Curl[u, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}];(*Ungauged*)

op2 = {D[\[Nu]1*(D[uy[x, y, z], x] - D[ux[x, y, z], y]), y] - 
   D[\[Nu]1*(D[ux[x, y, z], z] - D[uz[x, y, z], x]), z], 
  D[\[Nu]1*(D[uz[x, y, z], y] - D[uy[x, y, z], z]), z] - 
   D[\[Nu]1*(D[uy[x, y, z], x] - D[ux[x, y, z], y]), x],
  D[\[Nu]1*(D[ux[x, y, z], z] - D[uz[x, y, z], x]), x] - 
   D[\[Nu]1*(D[uz[x, y, z], y] - D[uy[x, y, z], z]), 
    y]};(*Ungauged*)

op3 = Div[\[Nu]1*Grad[u, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]; (*Coulomb gauged*)

op4 = {Inactive[Div][
   Inactive[Dot][\[Nu]1*IdentityMatrix[3], 
    Inactive[Grad][ux[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]], {x, y, z}], 
  Inactive[Div][
   Inactive[Dot][\[Nu]1*IdentityMatrix[3], 
    Inactive[Grad][uy[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]], {x, y, z}], 
  Inactive[Div][
   Inactive[Dot][\[Nu]1*IdentityMatrix[3], 
    Inactive[Grad][uz[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]], {x, y, 
    z}]}; (*Coulomb gauged*)

op5 = {Inactive[Div][\[Nu]1*
    Inactive[Grad][ux[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 
  Inactive[Div][\[Nu]1*Inactive[Grad][uy[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, 
    z}], Inactive[Div][\[Nu]1*
    Inactive[Grad][uz[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, 
    z}]}; (*Coulomb gauged*)

op6 = Curl[\[Nu]1*Curl[u, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] - 
   Grad[\[Nu]1*Div[u, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]; (*Coulomb gauged*)

{mvpAx, mvpAy, mvpAz} = 
 NDSolveValue[{op6 == \[CapitalGamma]n, \[CapitalGamma]d}, {ux, uy, 
   uz}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
   mesh];(*solve for magnetic vector potential A*)

(*flux density is curl of MVP A*)
{B1x, B1y, 
  B1z} = {(D[mvpAz[x, y, z], y] - 
    D[mvpAy[x, y, z], z]), (D[mvpAx[x, y, z], z] - 
    D[mvpAz[x, y, z], x]), 
  D[mvpAy[x, y, z], x] - D[mvpAx[x, y, z], y]};

Plot[{mvpAx[xp, a/2, a/2], mvpAy[xp, a/2, a/2], 
  mvpAz[xp, a/2, a/2]}, {xp, 0, b}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x distance (m)", "Potential (V.s/m)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "MVP along x directed line for y=z=a/2"]

Plot[Evaluate[{B1x, B1y, B1z} /. {x -> xp, y -> a/2, z -> a/2}], {xp, 
  0, b}, PlotLegends -> {"Bx", "By", "Bz"}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x distance (m)", "Flux Density(T)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Flux Density along x directed line for y=z=a/2"]
```

Here is an ungauged result:

[image: Ungauged Result]

There is an appreciable difference (factor 2) compared to the result in the paper for the flux density plotted along an x directed line midway in the iron cube. This problem has also been analyzed in a second paper but you need an IEEE Magnetics membership to access. Basically the results in the two papers are similar, so I am assuming the mistake is on my side, or MM implements the FEM solution somehow differently and it is not really applicable.

In the x direction Bx is continuous at the cube edge as the line is normal to the sudden discontinuity in the reluctance. Bz shows the required discontinuity jump, and Bz tends to 1T outside the iron cube as expected, but its amplitude at x=0 should be closer to 3T. By should show discontinuity also at the cube edge and its magnitude should be much higher.

My questions are:

1. Have I implemented the pde in MM correctly? I implemented various forms of the pde (op1 - op6 both gauged and ungauged) and all the gauged ones give the same result, and all the ungauged ones give the same result. I tried Inactive pde forms as well, but I think as "v1" is symmetric it does not do anything, it is just most MM examples show it being used.
2. The B=curl(A) result shows quite some discretization effects presumably due to the differentiation, yet the interpolated potential result looks quite smooth. How can that be improved without reducing mesh size?
3. Could it be that the way MM applies NDSolve to the FEM is not the best for this type of problem?

Any input most welcomed.

First Edit for some more insight:

A simpler variation that can be more easily verified is that of a solid permeable cylinder in a uniform field (Bz = 1T). An axisymmetric 3D (2D) simulation can be made. Here is some MM code for the axisymmetric Poisson equation:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

\[Mu]o = 4.0*\[Pi]*10^-7;
\[Mu]r = 1000.0;(*permeability iron region*)
h = 0.02; (*half height \
and radius of permeable cylinder*)
hAir = 0.1; (*height/width/depth \
air region*)
fluxDens = 1.0; (*z directed B field*)

(*create Mesh*)
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, -hAir}, {hAir, hAir}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.004^2, "MeshOrder" -> 2];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], RegionPlot[Rectangle[{0, -h}, {h, h}]]]

(*Solve*)
\[Nu] = 
 If[x <= h && -h <= y <= h, 1/(\[Mu]o*\[Mu]r), 
  1/\[Mu]o]; (*isotropic reluctivity*)
\[CapitalGamma]d = \
{DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == -fluxDens*hAir^2/2, x == hAir]};
op = Div[\[Nu]/x*Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}];
mvpA = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, \[CapitalGamma]d}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
ContourPlot[mvpA[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20]
(*Flux Density*)
{B1x, 
   B1y} = {D[mvpA[x, y], y]/x, -D[mvpA[x, y], x]/x};
Plot[mvpA[xp, h/2], {xp, 0.0001, hAir}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x distance (m)", "Magnetic Vector Potential (Wb/m)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Magnetic Vector Potential along x directed line for y=h/2"]
Plot[Evaluate[{B1x, B1y} /. {x -> xp, y -> h/2}], {xp, 0.0001, hAir}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Bx", "By"}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x distance (m)", "Flux Density(T)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Flux Density along x directed line for y=h/2"]
```

Here are the results 1) Azimuthal MVP 2) Flux Densities:

[image: 2D MVP cylinder]

[image: 2D Flux Density]

They compare favourably to that using the freely distributed FEMM software:

[image: FEMM 2D Normal Flux]

Now here is some 1/8 symmetry 3D code for the same problem but with  the ungauged Curl-Curl equation (v12+ with OpenCascade needed):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];

\[Mu]o = 4.0*\[Pi]*10^-7;
\[Mu]r = 1000.0;(*permeability iron region*)
h = 0.02; (*height and \
radius of permeable cylinder*)
hAir = 0.1; (*height/width/depth air \
region*)
fluxDens = 1.0; (*z directed B field*)

(*Create Air Region and Iron Cylinder*)
airShape = 
 OpenCascadeShape[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {hAir, hAir, hAir}]];
ironShape = 
  OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[airShape, 
   OpenCascadeShape[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, h}}, h]]];
regIron = 
  MeshRegion[
   ToElementMesh[OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[ironShape],
     MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity]];

(*Create Problem Region*)

combined = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[{airShape, ironShape}];
problemShape = OpenCascadeShapeSewing[{combined, ironShape}];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[problemShape];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = {Opacity[0.75], ColorData["BrightBands"][#]} & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors, 
  "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> White]]

(*Create Mesh*)

mrf = With[{rmf1 = RegionMember[regIron]}, 
   Function[{vertices, volume}, 
    Block[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} = Mean[vertices];
     If[rmf1[{x, y, z}], volume > 0.002^3, 
      volume > (2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - h^2) + 0.002)^3]]]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MeshRefinementFunction -> mrf, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01^3, "MeshOrder" -> 2]
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]

(*Solve*)
\[Nu] = 
 If[x^2 + y^2 \[LessSlantEqual] h^2 && z \[LessSlantEqual] h, 
  1/(\[Mu]r*\[Mu]o), 
  1/\[Mu]o]; (*isotropic reluctivity*)
\[CapitalGamma]d = \
{DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == 0, y == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == -fluxDens*hAir/2, y == hAir], 
  DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == 0, x == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == fluxDens*hAir/2, x == hAir], 
  DirichletCondition[uz[x, y, z] == 0, z == 0 || y == 0 || x == 0]};
\[CapitalGamma]n = {0, 0, 0};
u = {ux[x, y, z], uy[x, y, z], uz[x, y, z]};
op = Curl[\[Nu]*Curl[u, {x, y, z}], {x, y, 
   z}];(*Ungauged*)
mvpA = {mvpAx, mvpAy, mvpAz} = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == \[CapitalGamma]n, \[CapitalGamma]d}, {ux, uy, 
    uz}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];

(*flux density = curl A*)
{Bx, By, 
   Bz} = {(D[mvpAz[x, y, z], y] - 
     D[mvpAy[x, y, z], z]), (D[mvpAx[x, y, z], z] - 
     D[mvpAz[x, y, z], x]), 
   D[mvpAy[x, y, z], x] - D[mvpAx[x, y, z], y]};

Plot[{mvpAx[xp, 0, h/2], mvpAy[xp, 0, h/2], mvpAz[xp, 0, h/2]}, {xp, 
  0, hAir}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x distance (m)", "Potential (Wb/m)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "MVP along x directed line for y=0,z=h/2"]
Plot[Evaluate[{Bx, By, Bz} /. {x -> xp, y -> 0, z -> h/2}], {xp, 0, 
  hAir}, PlotLegends -> {"Bx", "By", "Bz"}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x distance (m)", "Flux Density(T)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Flux Density along x directed line for y=0,z=h/2"]
Plot[Evaluate[{Bx, By, Bz} /. {x -> 0, y -> yp, z -> h/2}], {yp, 0, 
  hAir}, PlotLegends -> {"Bx", "By", "Bz"}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {"y distance (m)", "Flux Density(T)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Flux Density along y directed line for x=0,z=h/2"]
```

Here is the mesh and result:

[image: 3D Mesh with 1/8 Cylinder]

[image: 3D Result 1/8 Cylinder]

Again the 3D result gives a lower flux density in the cylinder than expected, even though Bz is 1T  outside of the cylinder as required. In summary I still do not know why the result is in error. As User21 points out maybe it is the applied boundary conditions, but I have not found a condition that makes it right. While I had/have access to advanced 3D software like Opera and Maxwell, I like understanding the basics as well and Mathematica is great for that.

As reference the 3D code for the cylinder takes 23sec to run on an early 2011 MacBookPro with 4 cores and updated to 16Gig Ram + SSD.

Comment: It looks a bit as if the boundary conditions are not quite correct. Have you double checked those?

Comment: I have used the same boundary conditions in the mentioned paper, and they are also the same ones given in this paper: IEEE Trans. Magnetics "Three Dimensional  Magnetostatic analysis using structure mesh and nodal elements" Zhang and Kumar, 2011. So unless both are missing information  the 10 Dirichlet  conditions should be correct. However, contrary to what I said the results in the two papers are different to each other. The By and Bx fields in the 2011 paper peak at the cube edge at 0.5T, while Bz at the edge is a significantly lower 3.8T. So it brings into question both results as target.

Comment: Where you able to figure this out in the mean while? If not I'll set a bounty. Let me know.

Comment: No I have still not been able to figure why I do not get the correct result. I started to think maybe I need to impose an interface condition at the material-air but after reading some textbooks and papers this should not be necessary. My understanding is the “A” mvp formulation should work, but it’s disadvantage is the many degrees of freedom leads to an ill conditioned matrix requiring longer solution time. I would very much welcome a bounty, as the real problem I want to try involves currents.

Comment: @Greenasnz I have several examples of FEM simulation involved vector potential in a case of coil with current   - see my answer on  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/513834/current-density-in-a-3d-loop-discretising-a-model/515657#515657

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the link. Nice result. I was also able to simulate a coil and get a reasonable result for the case uniform permeability, that's why I really needed a vector potential solution, event though the problem presented is homogenous. Its just that as soon as I added the iron everything went wrong I guess for the reason "xzczd" mentions below.  Thanks heaps.

Comment: @Greenasnz The question is how they been able to get the right solution in a paper?  It looks like they used arbitrary vector in the same manner as  xzczd used `appro`.

Comment: The bounty is running out soon, you should let me know which of the answers should get the reward.

Comment: @Greenasnz, did you think about who should receive the bounty?

Comment: Version 13 has [ToGradedMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToGradedMesh.html) and [ElementMeshRegionProduct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMeshRegionProduct.html).

Answer (score 13):

I am a chemical engineer, so this is not in my field, but I am able to match the results given in the [reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3096485_An_incomplete_gauge_formulation_for_3D_nodal_finite-element_magnetostatics).

## Background

According to [COMSOL's Multiphysics Cyclopedia](https://www.comsol.com/multiphysics/magnetostatics-theory?parent=electromagnetics-072-132), the magnetostatic equation for linear materials with no free currents can be represented by:

$$- \nabla  \cdot \left( {{\mu _0}{\mu _R}\nabla {V_m}} \right) = 0$$

Where $V_m$ is the scalar magnetic potential, $\mu_0$ is the magnetic permeability, and $\mu_R$ is the relative permeability.

To match the results of the paper, we need only set a `DirichletCondition` of $V_m=0$ at the bottom, and `NeumannValue` of 1 at the top.  The remaining boundaries are default.

## Meshing

Anisotropic meshing where we apply boundary layers at the interface will help eliminate error due to discontinuous jump in $\mu_0$.

The following code defines functions that will help us with the boundary layer meshing for simple geometry:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(* Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Quad Mesh*)
pointsToMesh[data_] :=
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
unitMeshGrowth[n_, r_] := 
 Table[(r^(j/(-1 + n)) - 1.)/(r - 1.), {j, 0, n - 1}]
unitMeshGrowth2Sided [nhalf_, r_] := (1 + Union[-Reverse@#, #])/2 &@
  unitMeshGrowth[nhalf, r]
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := (xf - x0) unitMeshGrowth[n, r] + x0
firstElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@First@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
lastElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@Last@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
findGrowthRate[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Quiet@Abs@
   FindRoot[firstElmHeight[x0, xf, n, r] - fElm, {r, 1.0001, 100000}, 
     Method -> "Brent"][[1, 2]]
meshGrowthByElm[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 N@Sort@Chop@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, findGrowthRate[x0, xf, n, fElm]]
meshGrowthByElm0[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm[0, len, n, fElm]
meshGrowthByElmSym[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 With[{mid = Mean[{x0, xf}]}, 
  Union[meshGrowthByElm[mid, x0, n, fElm], 
   meshGrowthByElm[mid, xf, n, fElm]]]
meshGrowthByElmSym0[len_, n_, fElm_] := 
 meshGrowthByElmSym[0, len, n, fElm]
reflectRight[pts_] := With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{1}, {Last@pts}]},
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
reflectLeft[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{-1}, {First@pts}]},
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
flipSegment[l_] := (#1 - #2) & @@ {First[#], #} &@Reverse[l];
extendMesh[mesh_, newmesh_] := Union[mesh, Max@mesh + newmesh]
uniformPatch[dist_, n_] := With[{d = dist}, Subdivide[0, d, n]]
uniformPatch[p1_, p2_, n_] := With[{d = p2 - p1}, Subdivide[0, d, n]]
```

Using the above code, we can create the 1/8 symmetry mesh:

```
(* Define parameters *)
μo = 4.0*π*10^-7;
μr = 1000.0 ;(*iron relative permeability*)
a = 0.02 ;(*iron cube length(s)*)
airRegionScale = 
  5;(*integer scaling factor of air region to iron region*)
fluxDensity = 1.0;(*applied flux density in z direction*)
b = airRegionScale*a;
(* Association for Clearer Region Assignment *)
reg = <|"iron" -> 1, "air" -> 3|>;
(* Create anisotropic mesh segments *)
sxi = flipSegment@meshGrowthByElm0[a, 15, a/50];
sxa = meshGrowthByElm0[b - a, 30, a/50];
segx = extendMesh[sxi, sxa];
rpx = pointsToMesh@segx;
(* Create a tensor product grid from segments *)
rp = RegionProduct[rpx, rpx, rpx];
HighlightMesh[rp, Style[1, Orange]]
(* Extract Coords from RegionProduct *)
crd = MeshCoordinates[rp];
(* grab hexa element incidents RegionProduct mesh *)
inc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[rp, 3];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, 
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[inc]}];
(* Extract bmesh *)
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh];
(* Iron RegionMember Function *)
Ω3Diron = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, a, a}];
rmf = RegionMember[Ω3Diron];
regmarkerfn = If[rmf[#], reg["iron"], reg["air"]] &;
(* Get mean coordinate of each hexa for region marker assignment *)
mean = Mean /@ GetElementCoordinates[mesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ 
    ElementIncidents[mesh["MeshElements"]] // First;
regmarkers = regmarkerfn /@ mean;
(* Create and view element mesh *)
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> mesh["Coordinates"], 
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[inc, regmarkers]}];
Graphics3D[
 ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[bmesh, 
  VertexColors -> (ColorData["BrightBands"] /@ 
     Rescale[regmarkerfn /@ bmesh["Coordinates"]])], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Cube mesh]

## PDE Setup and Solution

The setup and solution is straightforward and given by the following code:

```
(* Setup and solve PDE system *)
mu[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Piecewise[{{μo μr, ElementMarker == reg["iron"]}}, μo]
parmop = Inactive[
    Div][{{-mu, 0, 0}, {0, -mu, 0}, {0, 0, -mu}}.Inactive[Grad][
     vm[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}];
op = parmop /. {mu -> mu[x, y, z]};
nvtop = NeumannValue[1, z == b];
dc = DirichletCondition[vm[x, y, z] == 0, z == 0];
pde = {op == nvtop, dc};
vmfun = NDSolveValue[pde, vm, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh];
```

## Post-Processing

Because there are two material domains, one must apply different $\mu_R$ to the gradient of the scalar potential $V_m$ to estimate the flux properly as shown below:

```
(* Gradient of interpolation function *)
gradfn = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][#], Derivative[0, 1, 0][#], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][#]} &;
ifgrad = {ifgradx, ifgrady, ifgradz} = gradfn@vmfun;
(* Region dependent magnetic flux density *)
B[x_, y_, z_] := 
 If[rmf[{x, y, z}], μo μr, μo ] {ifgradx[x, y, z], 
   ifgrady[x, y, z], ifgradz[x, y, z]}
(* magnetic flux density plot *)
Plot[Evaluate@B[xp, 12.5/20 a, 12.5/20 a], {xp, 0, b}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Bx", "By", "Bz"}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x distance (m)", "Flux Density(T)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Flux Density along x directed line for y=z=12.5 mm"]
```

[image: Magnetic Flux Density]

This plot matches the Scalar Potential line of the plot given in Figure 3 of the [reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3096485_An_incomplete_gauge_formulation_for_3D_nodal_finite-element_magnetostatics).  Additionally, note that in the OP, not only was $B_z$ about 1/2 the expected max value, the min value did not approach zero like it does in this solution and Figure 3.

For completeness, I added an overlay of the *Mathematica* solution with literature.  Due to my refinement strategy, I can support a sharper interface for $B_y$ and $B_z$ components and hence my solution leads their Scalar Potential solution.  Additionally, we should note that the literature reference plotted the B values at 12.5 mm versus 10 mm in the OP.

[image: Overlay]

## Comparison to another code (COMSOL)

I have a temporary license that gives me access to the AC/DC module that has a Magnetic Fields,No Currents interface.  It provides similar results to the *Mathematica* solution.

[image: COMSOL Solution]

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, but question actually is about vector potential application to solve this problem. Nevertheless you solution can be used as reference point as in a paper sited by OP.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks very, very much.  Yes as Alex suggested I will eventually need a vector potential solution as eventually I will have currents and not a homogenous pde. But verifying the solution in the first paper given is a big help. Also, your use of refined meshing at the interfaces, use of markers and flux density evaluation are extremely helpful.

Comment: Actually the PDE can be simply defined as `-mu[x, y, z] Laplacian[vm[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == nvtop`. Though mathematically this equation is incorrect (`mu[x, y, z]` is in the wrong position), `NDSolve` will still transform it to the desired formal form.

Comment: @xzczd, I think the way go is to put the `mu` inside the inactive. If it's outside it will be pulled into it internally and the difference will be compensated. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#588198981) in the documentation.

Comment: @user21 A matter of taste in my view. Build the equation with `Inactive` is unambiguous but longer, mine is mathematically wrong but brief.

Comment: @xzczd, got it, thanks.

Comment: @Greenasnz, Tim made a proposal to add anisotropic meshing capabilities to the FEM mesh generation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240408/18437). If you think this is worthwhile, consider giving this proposal an upvote

Answer (score 11):

I can answer the first question.

> Have I implemented the pde in MM correctly?

No, both gauged one and ungauged one are incorrect.

The underlying issue is quite similar to that discussed [in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200366/1871). In short, Coulomb gauging results in a Poisson equation $\text{div}(\text{grad}(\mathbf{A}))=\mathbf{J}$, **only if the permeability ($1/\nu$ in the paper and `1/ν1` in your question) is constant, but piecewise constant is not constant**.

Thus `op3`, `op4`, `op5`, `op6` are just wrong. Then how about `op1` and `op2`? It's the `ν1` that's not defined properly. Mathematically, when the piecewise constant coefficient is differentiated, a `DiracDelta` will be generated at the discontinuity, which cannot be ignored in this problem, or the continuity of the solution will be ruined. Nevertheless, this is just missed when a `If[……]` is differentiated:

```
D[If[x > 3, 1, 2], x]
(* If[x > 3, 0, 0] *)
```

The simplest solution is to approximate the piecewise constant with a continuous function:

```
appro = With[{k = 10^4}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &]; 
ν1 = 
 Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
   PiecewiseExpand@If[x <= a && y <= a && z <= a, 1/(μr μo), 1/μo] /. 
  UnitStep -> appro
```

With this modification, `op1` or `op2` leads to the following:

[image]

As we can see, $B_z$ is close to `3`, which is the desired result. I'm now on my laptop with 8G RAM only so can't do further test, but using a finer mesh should improve the quality of graphics.

---

### Update: A FDM Approach

The convergency of the solution above turns out to be rather slow. Even if we turn to the gauged equation, the solution is sensitive to the sharpness of `appro`. (Check [Alex's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231375/1871) for more info. ) Since there doesn't seem to exist an easy way to avoid symbolic differentiation of $\nu$ when `FiniteElement` of `NDSolve` is chosen, let's turn to finite difference method (FDM).

First, generate the general difference equation of the PDE system. I don't use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) here because the difference scheme turns out to be critical for this problem, and naive discretization using `pdetoae` simply doesn't work well.

```
ClearAll[fw, bw, delta]
SetAttributes[#, HoldAll] & /@ {fw, bw};

fw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{Δ = delta@ToString@x}, Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x + Δ}, {x -> x}})/Δ]
bw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{Δ = delta@ToString@x}, Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x}, {x -> x - Δ}})/Δ]

delta[a_ + b_] := delta@a + delta@b
delta[k_. delta[_]] := 0
var = {x, y, z};
grad = Function[expr, fw@D[expr, #] & /@ var];
div = Function[expr, Total@MapThread[bw@D@## &, {expr, var}]];    
curlf = With[{ϵ = LeviCivitaTensor[3]}, 
   expr \[Function] 
    Table[Sum[ϵ[[i, j, k]] fw@D[expr[[k]], var[[j]]], {j, 3}, {k, 3}], {i, 3}]];

μo = 4 π 10^-7;
μr = 1000;
a = 2/100;
airRegionScale = 3;
b = airRegionScale a;
fluxDensity = 1;
ν1 = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
   PiecewiseExpand@If[x <= a && y <= a && z <= a, 1/(μr μo), 1/μo];

u = Through[{ux, uy, uz} @@ var];
eq = Thread /@ {Cross[grad@ν1, curlf@u] - ν1 div@grad@u == 0};
```

Still, it's OK to use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the discretization of the b.c.s:

```
Clear[order, rhs]
(Evaluate[order @@ #] = 0) & /@ 
  Partition[Flatten@{{u[[1]], y, #} & /@ {0, b}, {u[[2]], x, #} & /@ {0, b}, 
     Table[{u[[3]], var, boundary}, {var, {x, y, z}}, {boundary, {0, b}}]}, 3];
order[__] = 1;
rhs[u[[1]], y, b] = -fluxDensity b/2;
rhs[u[[2]], x, b] = fluxDensity b/2;
rhs[__] = 0;
bc = Table[D[func, {var, order[func, var, boundary]}] == rhs[func, var, boundary] /. 
    var -> boundary, {func, u}, {var, {x, y, z}}, {boundary, {0, b}}]

points = 70; domain = {0, b}; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[u, {grid, grid, grid}, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
del2 = #[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]] &;

aebc = {Identity /@ #, del /@ #2, del2 /@ #3} & @@@ ptoafunc@bc;

Block[{delta}, delta["x"] = delta["y"] = delta["z"] = Subtract @@ domain/(1 - points);
  ae = Table[eq, {x, del@grid}, {y, del@grid}, {z, del@grid}]];

disvar = Outer[#[#2, #3, #4] &, {ux, uy, uz}, grid, grid, grid, 1] // Flatten;
{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[{ae, aebc} // Flatten, disvar]; // AbsoluteTiming
sollst = LinearSolve[marray, -N@barray]; // AbsoluteTiming
solfunclst = 
  ListInterpolation[#, {grid, grid, grid}, InterpolationOrder -> 3] & /@ 
   ArrayReshape[sollst, {3, points, points, points}];
```

**Warning**: for `points = 70`, the required RAM is:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^3. GB
(* 102.004 GB *)
```

Finally, visualization. Notice I've chosen a smaller `airRegionScale`, which seems to be the parameter chosen by the original paper.

```
{B1x, B1y, B1z} = Curl[# @@ var & /@ solfunclst, var];
Plot[{B1x, B1y, B1z} /. {x -> xp, y -> a/2, z -> a/2} // Evaluate, {xp, 0, b}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Bx", "By", "Bz"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x distance (m)", "Flux Density(T)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Flux Density along x directed line for y=z=a/2",
 Epilog -> InfiniteLine[{a, 0}, {0, 1}]]
```

[image]

In calculation above I've chosen a dense grid to obtain a better resolution around the interface, but even with a coarse grid like `points = 20`, the result isn't that bad:

[image]

Comment: It is Ok for this community, but in papers they used $\nu$ directly as it is. But they also used iterations to find numerical solution. May be  we can do this  with low level FEM?

Comment: @xzczd, never occurred to me that the If / Piecewise permeability/reluctivity might be the problem as they are  widely used in MM examples. Still a bit unclear why Tim above could use Piecewise for the scalar potential solution, but here it does not work. I will certainly try the function approach with a finer mesh, especially to see if Bx and By peak towards 1.0. They seem to be hovering around 0.5 which are the values the second restricted access paper I quoted showed as a result. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Alex By "as it is" do you mean not using the continuous approximation? If so, I guess we need to implement it in a very low level way, because even those functions under `NDSolve\`FEM\`` context seem to serve the [formal PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225711/1871) only, and there doesn't seem to exist a easy way to avoid symbolic differentiation of `ν1` when transforming to the formal PDE. I sincerely hope I'm wrong.

Comment: @Greenasnz It's because symbolic differentiation doesn't happen on $ν$ in Tim's solution. You can use the tool linked in my last comment to check how the PDE system is transformed internally.

Comment: @xzczd, could you explain to me what you mean by avoid symbolic differentiation? `Inavtive[Div][f[x,y].Inactive[Grad][u, {x,y}],{x,y}]` does not do any symbolic differentiation. Do I understand correctly, that you want an operator that does `f[x,y].Inactive[Div][Inactive[Grad][u,{x,y}],{x,y}]` where `f[x,y]` is now a scalar?

Comment: @user21 I mean, currently there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to transform the equation $\nabla × \mu \nabla× \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{J}$ （where $\mu$ is **not** a constant) to the formal PDE **without** symbolically differentiating $\mu$.

Comment: @xzczd, would that not be a matter of filling out the coefficients for this: `Plus @@@ Table[
  Inactive[Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
   Inactive[Grad][dep, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], {dep, {Ax[x, y, z], 
    Ay[x, y, z], Az[x, y, z]}}, {dep, {Ax[x, y, z], Ay[x, y, z], 
    Az[x, y, z]}}]`?

Comment: @xzczd, we have the conference coming up so I can not look into this right now, but there is nothing obvious to me why something like this would not work.

Comment: @user21 It's really hard to, the `Curl` is in the way…

Comment: @xzczd, yes, this is not trivial but I think it should be possible. Thanks for looking into tjhis.

Comment: This is a bit belated, I am looking into [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271650/calculating-the-3d-magnetic-vector-field-of-a-permanent-magnet-with-shape-given/273112?noredirect=1#273112). Say, we wanted a version of `target = Curl[\[Mu][x, y, z] Curl[{Ax[x, y, z], Ay[x, y, z], Az[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] // Expand;` as a set of Div/Grads. We could use this then: `m = \[Mu][x, y, z];` and then use:

Comment: `idea=Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSmNmYGAoZgESPpnFJQheQE5pcRoTkJHGCBLiABKeeYnJJZllqcUgRS6ZZWB\
pCCe/BJc5IF4mkGZAECRIQnhsQCLGysDYybkY5JgKMFkJJquQdOJwLcgs96LEFIhZIEWOV\
ZjmoNpLhjzdwgpiFCuQCMnMTS3O/\
A8ERIYTLqvIM5KEAK8YogFOUvrDayzxYVVJg7AaZNkaSYhwmh0+\
2ZrCXErVVDaIcyQFBRz54UfzInC4ZWsiAmcQF4hUDytKg2M0W5ORrWnQFBoEdQ4AJDDzmQ\
=="]`

Comment: `Activate[idea] - target`

Comment: @user21 Wow, this is really a step forward. How do you find this? Do you find a systemmatic way to transform these operators to the formal PDE? (A quick test shows that, with `MeshOrder -> 2` mesh, `NDSolve` is having difficulty in finding the solution of `idea`. With `MeshOrder -> 1` mesh, a solution can be found, but the precision of `B1x`, etc. seems to become a problem. )

Comment: @xzczd, I used this `Plus @@@ 
 Table[Inactive[Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} . 
    Inactive[Grad][dep, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], {dep, {Ax[x, y, z], 
    Ay[x, y, z], Az[x, y, z]}}, {dep, {Ax[x, y, z], Ay[x, y, z], 
    Az[x, y, z]}}]` copied that and then started to fill in the coefficients until `Activate[idea] - target` was zero. I started with the first row: `Activate[idea][[1]] - target[[1]]`, there I fist matched the pure 2nd order derivatives (like Derivative[2,0,0]) and then then when on to the mixed '2nd' derivatives (like Derivative[1,0,1]) the other terms ...

Comment: ... then just vanished. Had they not vanished, I'd have to add more PDE terms. It's unfortunate that this form of the equation does not seem to help :-( ... Are you planing to update your post? I am confident that the other types of equations (mentioned in Alex post) can also be created this way.

Comment: @xzczd We continued with calculation of magnet fields for different geometries and we came across a problem with the FEM Solver we are trying to figure out. Your approximation of the piecewise constant circumvents the problem. We would therefor politeley ask you to join our chat about this topic Chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139042/discussion-between-tschibi-and-user21 Question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271650/calculating-the-3d-magnetic-vector-field-of-a-permanent-magnet-with-shape-given

Answer (score 11):

I am physicist from the first  education, so it is apparently my field. As it follows from my experience in 3D FEM testing with application to the magnetic field calculation there is a problem with equation $\nabla \times (\nu \nabla \times \vec {A})=\vec {j}$. Therefore we prefer another form of this equation, for example, this one $\nabla \nu \times (\nabla \times \vec {A})+\nu \nabla \times \nabla \times\vec {A} =\vec {j}$ (ungauged form).
Then if we have Coulomb gauge $\nabla.\vec {A}$, it automatically turns to $\nabla \nu \times (\nabla \times \vec {A})-\nu \nabla ^2\vec {A} =\vec {j}$ (Coulomb gauge). Now we can compare two form using `mesh` from Tim Laska answer (thanks to him), and function `appro` from  xzczd answer (thanks to him as well). Let check Coulomb gauge first:

```
u = {ux[x, y, z], uy[x, y, z], uz[x, y, z]}; appro = 
 With[{k = 1. 10^4}, Tanh[k #]/2 + 1/2 &];
\[Nu]1 = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    PiecewiseExpand@If[x <= a && y <= a && z <= a, 1/(\[Mu]r), 1] /. 
   UnitStep -> 
    appro;(*permeability depending on iron cube in mesh*)\
\[CapitalGamma]d = {DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == 0, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == -fluxDensity*b/2, y == b], 
   DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == 0, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == fluxDensity*b/2, x == b], 
   DirichletCondition[uz[x, y, z] == 0, 
    y == b || y == 0 || x == 0 || x == b || z == 0 || z == b]};
\[CapitalGamma]n = {0, 0, 0};
op7 = Cross[Grad[\[Nu]1, {x, y, z}], Curl[u, {x, y, z}]] - \[Nu]1*
   Laplacian[u, {x, y, z}];(*Coulomb gauged*){mvpAx, mvpAy, mvpAz} = 
 NDSolveValue[{op7 == {0, 0, 0}, \[CapitalGamma]d}, {ux, uy, 
   uz}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];
```

Visualization
[image: Figure 1]

Now let check ungauged form

```
u = {ux[x, y, z], uy[x, y, z], uz[x, y, z]}; appro = 
 With[{k = 2. 10^4}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
\[Nu]1 = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    PiecewiseExpand@If[x <= a && y <= a && z <= a, 1/(\[Mu]r), 1] /. 
   UnitStep -> 
    appro;(*permeability depending on iron cube in mesh*)\
\[CapitalGamma]d = {DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == 0, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == -fluxDensity*b/2, y == b], 
   DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == 0, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == fluxDensity*b/2, x == b], 
   DirichletCondition[uz[x, y, z] == 0, 
    y == b || y == 0 || x == 0 || x == b || z == 0 || z == b]};
\[CapitalGamma]n = {0, 0, 0};
op7 = Cross[Grad[\[Nu]1, {x, y, z}], Curl[u, {x, y, z}]] - \[Nu]1*
   Laplacian[u, {x, y, z}]; op8 = 
 Cross[Grad[\[Nu]1, {x, y, z}], Curl[u, {x, y, z}]] + \[Nu]1*
   Curl[Curl[u, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}];(*Coulomb gauged*){mvpAx, 
  mvpAy, mvpAz} = 
 NDSolveValue[{op8 == {0, 0, 0}, \[CapitalGamma]d}, {ux, uy, 
   uz}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];
```

[image: Figure 2]

It looks reasonable but pay attention how we play with `k` and with `Tanh[]`(Coulomb gauge) and `ArcTan[]` (ungauged form).
For reference we can compare 3 solution for problem of coil magnetic field first considered by N. Demerdash, T. Nehl and F. Fouad, "Finite element formulation and analysis of three dimensional magnetic field problems," in IEEE Transactions on Magnetics, vol. 16, no. 5, pp. 1092-1094, September 1980. doi: 10.1109/TMAG.1980.1060817. This solution explained without code on https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/513834/current-density-in-a-3d-loop-discretising-a-model/515657#515657
We have to calculate the vector potential and magnetic field of a rectangular coil with a current of 20A. The number of turns = 861. Inner cross section is 10.42cm×10.42cm, outer cross section is 15.24cm×15.24cm, coil height is 8.89cm. Here we show code for Closed Form Solution Algorithm (CFSA), BEM (Integral) and Mathematica FEM. CFSA code:

```
h = 0.0889; L1 = 0.1042; L2 = 0.1524; n = 861 (*16AWG wire*); J0 = \
20(*Amper*); j0 = 20*n/(h*(L2 - L1)/2); mu0 = 4 Pi 10^-7; b0 = j0 mu0;
bx[a_, b_, x_, y_, z_] := 
 z/(Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (-b + y + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + z^2])) - z/(
  Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (-b + y + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + z^2])) - z/(
  Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (b + y + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + z^2])) + z/(
  Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (b + y + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + z^2]))
by[a_, b_, x_, y_, z_] := 
 z/(Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (-a + x + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + z^2])) - z/(
  Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (a + x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + z^2])) - z/(
  Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (-a + x + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + z^2])) + z/(
  Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (a + x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + z^2]))
bz[a_, b_, x_, y_, 
  z_] := -((-b + y)/(
   Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + 
     z^2] (-a + x + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + z^2]))) - (-a + 
   x)/(Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (-b + y + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + z^2])) + (-b + y)/(
  Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (a + x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + z^2])) + (a + x)/(
  Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (-b + y + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + z^2])) + (b + y)/(
  Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (-a + x + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + z^2])) + (-a + x)/(
  Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (b + y + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + z^2])) - (b + y)/(
  Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (a + x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + z^2])) - (a + x)/(
  Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + 
    z^2] (b + y + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2 + z^2]))
da = (L2 - L1)/15/2;
dh = h/26/2; a = b = L1/2;
Bz[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Sum[bz[a + da (i - 1), b + da (i - 1), x, y, z + dh j], {i, 1, 
    16}, {j, -26, 26, 1}] + 
  Sum[bz[a, b, x, y, z + dh j], {j, -6, 6, 
    1}];
```

Code for BEM (Integral)

```
reg = RegionDifference[
   ImplicitRegion[-L2/2 <= x <= L2/2 && -L2/2 <= y <= L2/2 && -h/2 <= 
      z <= h/2, {x, y, z}], 
   ImplicitRegion[-L1/2 <= x <= L1/2 && -L1/2 <= y <= L1/2 && -h/2 <= 
      z <= h/2, {x, y, z}]];

j[x_, y_, z_] := Boole[{x, y, z} \[Element] reg]
jx[x_, y_, z_] := If[-y <= x <= y || y <= -x <= -y, Sign[y], 0]

jy[x_, y_, z_] := -jx[y, x, z]


Bx1[X_?NumericQ, Y_?NumericQ, Z_?NumericQ] := 
 b0/(4 Pi) NIntegrate[
    j[x, y, z] jy[x, y, 
      z] (Z - z)/(Sqrt[(x - X)^2 + (y - Y)^2 + (z - Z)^2])^3, {x, y, 
      z} \[Element] reg] // Quiet
By1[X_?NumericQ, Y_?NumericQ, 
  Z_?NumericQ] := -b0/(4 Pi) NIntegrate[
    j[x, y, z] jx[x, y, 
      z] (Z - z)/(Sqrt[(x - X)^2 + (y - Y)^2 + (z - Z)^2])^3, {x, y, 
      z} \[Element] reg] // Quiet
Bz1[X_?NumericQ, Y_?NumericQ, Z_?NumericQ] := 
 b0/(4 Pi) NIntegrate[
    j[x, y, z] (jx[x, y, z] (Y - y) - 
        jy[x, y, 
          z] (X - x))/(Sqrt[(x - X)^2 + (y - Y)^2 + (z - Z)^2])^3, {x,
       y, z} \[Element] reg] // Quiet
```

Code for FEM

```
eq1 = {Laplacian[A1[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == -j[x, y, z] jx[x, y, z], 
   Laplacian[A2[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == -j[x, y, z] jy[x, y, z]};
{Ax1, Ay1} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eq1, 
    DirichletCondition[{A1[x, y, z] == 0, A2[x, y, z] == 0}, 
     True]}, {A1, A2}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
    ImplicitRegion[-2 L2 <= x <= 2 L2 && -2 L2 <= y <= 
       2 L2 && -2 L2 <= z <= 2 L2, {x, y, z}]];
B = Evaluate[Curl[{Ax1[x, y, z], Ay1[x, y, z], 0}, {x, y, z}]];
```

Now we compute and visualize data

```
lst1 = Table[{z1, -b0 B[[3]] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0, 
      z -> z1}}, {z1, -.3, .3, .01}];
lst2 = Table[{z1, Bz[0, 0, z1] mu0 20/(4 Pi)}, {z1, -.3, .3, .01}];
lst3 = Table[{z1, -Bz1[0, 0, z1]}, {z1, -.3, .3, .01}];

{Region[reg], 
 Show[ListLinePlot[lst2, PlotStyle -> Orange, Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False], 
  ListPlot[{lst1, lst2, lst3}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"z", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(B\), \(z\)]\)"}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"FEM", "CFSA", "Integral"}]]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Alex, your result of the gauged formulation looks really close to what is in the paper for the ungauged vector and scalar potential derived solutions. The way you expressed the gauged form is much like an IEEE Magnetics paper from 1991, Vol 27, No. 5 by Preis, Bardi, Richter ...., in which they were of the opinion, and I quote, " that setting Curl(v*Curl(A)) - Grad(v*Div(A)=J is not the same as using the vector Poisson equation Div(v*Grad(A)=J , since it does not imply decoupling of the three components of vector potential".

Comment: @Greenasnz We can calibrate numerical solution using `k`. But how we can do it in an unknown case? I can recommend some BEM solution as shown on https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/513834/current-density-in-a-3d-loop-discretising-a-model/515657#515657

Comment: Alex, you may have a typo with the `;;` at the end of $\Gamma_D$ expression.  When I copy it verbatim, the code does not run.  If I remove one of the `;`, it runs.

Comment: I guess you've adjusted the parameters of Tim's `mesh` to make it denser?

Comment: @TimLaska Thank you very much for code debugging! I have corrected `;;`.

Comment: @xzczd Actually I am used `mesh` as it is `ElementMesh[{{0., 0.1}, {0., 0.1}, {0., 0.1}}, {HexahedronElement[
   "<" 79507 ">"]}]`

Comment: I fail to reproduce the result in _v12.1.1_, Win10. The following is the gauged result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1ksl.png ungauged: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1ksl.png Which version are you in?

Comment: @xzczd I am sorry! In the Coulomb gauge `k=10^4` and I am used `Tanh[k#]/2+1/2` in vv12.0-12.1 for Windows. In the ungauged case `k=2 10^4` with you `appro`. Code been corrected.

Answer (score 7):

Here I present an alternative solution to compute the magnetic flux density using the magnetic vector potential formulation, using `"RegionMarker"`, using $\nu$ directly as it is, and using an equivalent form of $\nabla \times ( \,\nu \nabla \times A)\,=J$ (ungauged) using `DiffusionPDETerm[]`,which already uses `Div[]`,`Grad[]` in `Inactive[]` form.

### Meshing

I use the anisotropic mesh made by Tim Laska, and added his code to have a complete answer. It is important to notice that this solution is possible only if our mesh has interior boundaries that define the different material regions of the domain. This is essential for using Element Markers.

```
(*Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Quad Mesh*)
pointsToMesh[data_] := 
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
unitMeshGrowth[n_, r_] := 
 Table[(r^(j/(-1 + n)) - 1.)/(r - 1.), {j, 0, n - 1}]
unitMeshGrowth2Sided[nhalf_, r_] := (1 + Union[-Reverse@#, #])/2 &@
  unitMeshGrowth[nhalf, r]
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := (xf - x0) unitMeshGrowth[n, r] + x0
firstElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@First@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
lastElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@Last@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
findGrowthRate[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Quiet@Abs@
   FindRoot[firstElmHeight[x0, xf, n, r] - fElm, {r, 1.0001, 100000}, 
     Method -> "Brent"][[1, 2]]
meshGrowthByElm[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 N@Sort@Chop@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, findGrowthRate[x0, xf, n, fElm]]
meshGrowthByElm0[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm[0, len, n, fElm]
meshGrowthByElmSym[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 With[{mid = Mean[{x0, xf}]}, 
  Union[meshGrowthByElm[mid, x0, n, fElm], 
   meshGrowthByElm[mid, xf, n, fElm]]]
meshGrowthByElmSym0[len_, n_, fElm_] := 
 meshGrowthByElmSym[0, len, n, fElm]
reflectRight[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{1}, {Last@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
reflectLeft[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{-1}, {First@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
flipSegment[l_] := (#1 - #2) & @@ {First[#], #} &@Reverse[l];
extendMesh[mesh_, newmesh_] := Union[mesh, Max@mesh + newmesh]
uniformPatch[dist_, n_] := With[{d = dist}, Subdivide[0, d, n]]
uniformPatch[p1_, p2_, n_] := With[{d = p2 - p1}, Subdivide[0, d, n]]
```

Creation of the 1/8 symmetry mesh:

```
a = 0.02;(*iron cube length(s)*)
airRegionScale = 
  5;(*integer scaling factor of air region to iron region*)
b = airRegionScale*a;
(*Association for Clearer Region Assignment*)
reg = <|"iron" -> 1, "air" -> 3|>;
(*Create anisotropic mesh segments*)
sxi = flipSegment@meshGrowthByElm0[a, 15, a/50];
sxa = meshGrowthByElm0[b - a, 30, a/50];
segx = extendMesh[sxi, sxa];
rpx = pointsToMesh@segx;
(*Create a tensor product grid from segments*)
rp = RegionProduct[rpx, rpx, rpx];
(*Extract Coords from RegionProduct*)
crd = MeshCoordinates[rp];
(*grab hexa element incidents RegionProduct mesh*)
inc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[rp, 3];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, 
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[inc]}];
(*Extract bmesh*)
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh];
(*Iron RegionMember Function*)
Ω3Diron = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, a, a}];
rmf = RegionMember[Ω3Diron];
regmarkerfn = If[rmf[#], reg["iron"], reg["air"]] &;
(*Get mean coordinate of each hexa for region marker assignment*)
mean = Mean /@ GetElementCoordinates[mesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ 
    ElementIncidents[mesh["MeshElements"]] // First;
regmarkers = regmarkerfn /@ mean;
(*Create and view element mesh*)
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> mesh["Coordinates"], 
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[inc, regmarkers]}, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
```

Remember that the mesh is of order 1.

### Parameters

Define the parameters. $\nu$ is specified with an `If` condition:

```
(*Define parameters*)
μo = 4.0*π*10^-7;
μr = 1000.0;(*iron relative permeability*)
fluxDensity = 1.0;(*applied flux density in z direction*)
ν1 = 
  If[ElementMarker == reg["iron"], 1/(μr μo), 1/μo];
```

### Boundary Conditions

Define boundary conditions:

```
Γd = {DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == 0, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == -fluxDensity*b/2, y == b], 
   DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == 0, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == fluxDensity*b/2, x == b], 
   DirichletCondition[uz[x, y, z] == 0, 
    y == b || y == 0 || x == 0 || x == b || z == 0 || z == b]};
Γn = {0, 0, 0};
```

### Set Up

Define the variables and setup the equation with `DiffusionPDETerm[]`
The diffusion PDETerm will be defined as a system of PDEs with dependent variables `{ux,uy,uz}`. In this case the diffusion coefficient $c$ is a tensor of rank 4 of the form $\{\{c_{1,1},\dotsb,c_{1,m}\},\dotsb,\{c_{m,1},\dotsb,c_{m,m}\}\}$ where each submatrix $c_{i,j}$ is an 3x3 matrix.

```
vars = {{ux[x, y, z], uy[x, y, z], uz[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}};
coefficients = {{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, ν1, 0}, {0, 0, ν1}}, {{0, 0, 
      0}, {-ν1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
      0}, {-ν1, 0, 0}}}, {{{0, -ν1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
      0}}, {{ν1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, ν1}}, {{0, 0, 
      0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, -ν1, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, -ν1}, {0, 0, 
      0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -ν1}, {0, 0, 
      0}}, {{ν1, 0, 0}, {0, ν1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}};
idea = DiffusionPDETerm[vars, coefficients];
```

### Solve

Solve the equation:

```
{mvpAx, mvpAy, mvpAz} = 
  NDSolveValue[{idea == Γn, Γd}, {ux, uy, 
    uz}, {x, y, z} ∈ 
    mesh];(*solve for magnetic vector potential A*)
```

### Post-processing

Compute the magnetic flux:

```
{B1x, B1y, 
   B1z} = {(D[mvpAz[x, y, z], y] - 
     D[mvpAy[x, y, z], z]), (D[mvpAx[x, y, z], z] - 
     D[mvpAz[x, y, z], x]), 
   D[mvpAy[x, y, z], x] - D[mvpAx[x, y, z], y]};
```

### Plot of B along the line y=z=12.5 mm

```
Plot[Evaluate[{B1x, B1y, B1z} /. {x -> xp, y -> 12.5/20 a, 
    z -> 12.5/20 a}], {xp, 0, b}, PlotLegends -> {"Bx", "By", "Bz"}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x distance (m)", "Flux Density(T)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Flux Density along x directed line for y=z=a/2"]
```

The plot matches
[image: Components of B along the line y=z=12.5 mm]

To compare, the plot from below shows the solution obtained from the scalar magnetic potential $Vm$ with the obtained here.
[image: Comparison between solutions]

Comment: (+1) great answer. Just to mention, you could use 'ToGradedMesh' and 'ElementMeshTegionProduct' to simplify the mesh generation.

Comment: "It is important to notice that this solution is possible only if our mesh has interior boundaries that define the different material regions of the domain. This is essential for using Element Markers." Actually `ν1 = If[x <= a && y <= a && z <= a, 1/(μr μo), 1/μo]` is enough. The graded mesh seems to play a critical role in this solution.

Answer (score 5):

I have also combined some of the contributions posted here (Tim, xzczd, Alex, User21) to look at the cylinder problem to get the correct answer in 3D even though it is a 2D problem. Foremost, I wanted to compare two quoted pde formulations:

op1 = Cross[Grad[[Nu]1, {x, y, z}], Curl[u, {x, y, z}]] - [Nu]1*
Laplacian[u, {x, y, z}]  given by Alex

and

op2 = Curl[[Nu]1*Curl[u, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] - [Nu]1*
Laplacian[u, {x, y, z}] that I quoted from a paper in the comments

here is the code, (it needs MM 12):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];

\[Mu]o = 4.0*\[Pi]*10^-7;
\[Mu]r = 1000.0;(*permeability iron region*)
h = 0.02; (*height and \
radius of permeable cylinder*)
hAir = 0.1; (*height/width/depth air \
region*)
fluxDens = 1.0; (*z directed B field*)
\[CapitalDelta] = \
0.001;(*mesh refinement region thickness around cylinder/air \
interface*)
(*Define Air Region and Iron Cylinder*)
airShape = 
 OpenCascadeShape[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {hAir, hAir, hAir}]];
ironShape = 
  OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[airShape, 
   OpenCascadeShape[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, h}}, h]]];
regIron = 
  MeshRegion[
   ToElementMesh[OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[ironShape],
     MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity]];
(*Create Problem Region*)

combined = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[{airShape, ironShape}];
problemShape = OpenCascadeShapeSewing[{combined, ironShape}];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[problemShape];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = {Opacity[0.75], ColorData["BrightBands"][#]} & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors, 
  "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> White]]
(*Define fine mesh buffer*)

bufferShape = 
  OpenCascadeShapeDifference[
   OpenCascadeShape[
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h + \[CapitalDelta]}}, 
     h + \[CapitalDelta]]], 
   OpenCascadeShape[
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h - \[CapitalDelta]}}, 
     h - \[CapitalDelta]]]];
regBuffer = 
  MeshRegion[
   ToElementMesh[
    OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[bufferShape], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity]];
(*Create Mesh*)

mrf = With[{rmf1 = RegionMember[regIron], 
    rmf2 = RegionMember[regBuffer]}, 
   Function[{vertices, volume}, 
    Block[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} = Mean[vertices];
     If[rmf1[{x, y, z}] && ! rmf2[{x, y, z}], volume > 0.002^3, 
      If[rmf2[{x, y, z}], volume > 0.001^3, 
       volume > (2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - h^2) + 0.001)^3]]]]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MeshRefinementFunction -> mrf, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01^3, "MeshOrder" -> 2]
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
(*Solve*)
\[Nu] = 
 If[x^2 + y^2 \[LessSlantEqual] h^2 && z \[LessSlantEqual] h, 
  1/(\[Mu]r*\[Mu]o), 1/\[Mu]o]; (*isotropic reluctivity*)
appro = 
 With[{k = 5*10^4}, Tanh[k #]/2 + 1/2 &];
\[Nu]1 = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    PiecewiseExpand@If[x^2 + y^2 <= h^2 && z <= h, 1/(\[Mu]r), 1] /. 
   UnitStep -> appro;
\[CapitalGamma]d = {DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == 0, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[ux[x, y, z] == -fluxDens*hAir/2, y == hAir], 
   DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == 0, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[uy[x, y, z] == fluxDens*hAir/2, x == hAir], 
   DirichletCondition[uz[x, y, z] == 0, z == 0 || y == 0 || x == 0]};
\[CapitalGamma]n = {0, 0, 0};
u = {ux[x, y, z], uy[x, y, z], uz[x, y, z]};
op1 = Cross[Grad[\[Nu]1, {x, y, z}], Curl[u, {x, y, z}]] - \[Nu]1*
   Laplacian[u, {x, y, z}]; (*given in forum*)
op2 = 
 Curl[\[Nu]1*Curl[u, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] - \[Nu]1*
   Laplacian[
    u, {x, y, z}]; (*from paper quoted in comments*)
mvpA = {mvpAx, 
   mvpAy, mvpAz} = 
  NDSolveValue[{op2 == \[CapitalGamma]n, \[CapitalGamma]d}, {ux, uy, 
    uz}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];
(*flux density = curl A*)
{Bx, By, 
   Bz} = {(D[mvpAz[x, y, z], y] - 
     D[mvpAy[x, y, z], z]), (D[mvpAx[x, y, z], z] - 
     D[mvpAz[x, y, z], x]), 
   D[mvpAy[x, y, z], x] - D[mvpAx[x, y, z], y]};
(*plots*)
Plot[{mvpAx[a, a, h/2], mvpAy[a, a, h/2], 
  mvpAz[a, a, hAir]}, {a, 0, hAir}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x=y distance (m)", "Potential (Wb/m)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "MVP along x=y line at z=h/2"]
Plot[Evaluate[{Bx, By, Bz} /. {x -> a, y -> a, z -> h/2}], {a, 0, 
  hAir}, PlotLegends -> {"Bx", "By", "Bz"}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x=y distance (m)", "Flux Density(T)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Flux Density along x=y line at z=h/2"]
```

With op1 the flux density at z=h/2 and on a line x=y (i.e., 45 degree radial) is:

[image: Using op1]

With op2 the flux density at z=h/2 and on a line x=y (ie., 45 degree radial) is:

[image: Using op2]

Here is the mesh for reference, with finer mesh around the air/iron interface.

[image: Mesh with refined interface]

In NDSolveValue using op2 seems to give a bit more accurate answer. I am not sure, but maybe op1 gives a relatively accurate answer for the cube case due to hexahedron elements being used. Getting out of my depth there. In any case, as Alex says, choosing the function for the reluctivity, while providing an answer, is a significant weakness in obtaining a solution using MM at the moment for this type of problem.

Comment: What are you used as a reference point for this solution?