# How to use MMA to solve the minimal surface?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, differential-geometry

There is a great [old post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72203/21532), but since *MMA* greatly improves the ability of solving *differential equations*, especially the *Region* can be used to define the range of variables. So I ask it again. As the [Lagrange's Equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangesEquation.html):
$$(1+f_y^2)f_{xx}+(1+f_x^2)f_{yy}=2f_xf_yf_{xy}$$So we can make expression in *MMA*:

```
NDSolve[{(1+D[u[x,y],y]^2)D[u[x,y],{x,2}]+(1+D[u[x,y],x]^2)D[u[x,y],{y,2}]==2D[u[x,y],x]D[u[x,y],y]D[u[x,y],x,y],
DirichletCondition[u[x,y]==2,x^2+y^2==4 Cosh[1]^2],
DirichletCondition[u[x,y]==-2,x^2+y^2==4 Cosh[1]^2]},u[x,y],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
```

But it doesn't look like *MMA* can solve this differential equation. Did I make a mistake? I don't want to get the exact solution, I just want to get the numerical solution and plot it.

---

I actually know the solution of this differential equation, and I can plot it with this code:

```
a=2;
RevolutionPlot3D[{a*Cosh[z/a],z},{z,-2,2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Another point, since you consider the case of a surface specified as $f(x,y)$, it makes sense to present the solution exactly in this form, which would be something like $f(x,y)=\cosh^{-1}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.

Comment: @yarchik Didn't I define the boundary conditions for the differential equation? I want to do here is to get a minimal surface of the catenary type, like the following graphic

Comment: You did. However, I wanted to point of some slight inconsistencies in the original post. You have one equation in a formula form, and a list of 3 equations in the `NDSolve`. And finally, the solution that you presented is not in the form you asked for.

Comment: @yode `NDSolve`gives a hint "NDSolve::femnlmdor: The maximum derivative order of the nonlinear PDE coefficients for the Finite Element Method is larger than 1. It may help to rewrite the PDE in inactive form." .Did you try to rewrite the pde?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, another friend reminded me to rewrite pde with inactive form, but I don't know how to modify it...

Comment: As to the analytic solution, I agree with @yarchik . Actually I fail to understand the question until I see cvgmt's answer below…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Since the Lagrange's Equation only work for the surfaces as graphs of functions,that is,the surface must be the form of `{x,y,f[x,y]}` and `{x, y} ∈ 2D region`,so it doesn't work for general parametric surfaces.
- Here we seperate the parametric surface to two graphs of functions and using the divergence form of the Lagrange's Equation respectly.

```
a = 2;
h1 = 3;
h2 = 4;
catenary[z_] = a*Cosh[z/a];
ParametricPlot[{catenary[z], z}, {z, -h2, h1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Cyan, Green}]
```

[image]

- Divergence form of the Lagrange's Equation for two graphs.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 2;
h1 = 3;
h2 = 4;
catenary[z_] = a*Cosh[z/a];
reg1 = Annulus[{0, 0}, {catenary[0], catenary[h1]}];
reg2 = Annulus[{0, 0}, {catenary[0], catenary[h2]}];
sol1 = NDSolve[{Inactive[Div][Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}]/Sqrt[
      1 + Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}] . Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}]], {x, y}] == 
     0, {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == catenary[0]^2],
      DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == h1, 
      x^2 + y^2 == catenary[h1]^2]}}, u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg1];
sol2 = NDSolve[{Inactive[Div][Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}]/Sqrt[
      1 + Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}] . Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}]], {x, y}] == 
     0, {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == catenary[0]^2],
      DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == -h2, 
      x^2 + y^2 == catenary[h2]^2]}}, u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg2];
graphs = {Plot3D[u[x, y] /. sol1, {x, y} ∈ reg1, 
   PlotStyle -> Green, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot3D[u[x, y] /. sol2, {x, y} ∈ reg2, PlotStyle -> Cyan, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All], 
  RevolutionPlot3D[{a*Cosh[z/a], z}, {z, -h2, h1}]}
Show[graphs, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The pde might be rewritten as first order pde with inactive parts:

```
pde= (1 + D[z[x, y], y]^2) D[z[x, y], {x, 2}] + (1 + D[z[x, y], x]^2) D[z[x, y], {y, 2}] -2 D[z[x, y], x] D[z[x, y], y] D[z[x, y], x, y]
```

first order form:

```
    Div[ {Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y], Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, y]}, {x, 
     y}] + Derivative[1, 0][z][x, 
     y] Grad[Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, y], {x, y}] . 
     Cross[{Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y], Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, y]}] - 
   Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, 
     y] Grad[Derivative[1, 0  ][z][x, y], {x, y}] . 
     Cross[{Derivative[1, 0  ][z][x, y], 
       Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, y]}] == pde  // Simplify (*True*)
```

With modiffied dirichlet conditions Mathematica is able to solve the problem in the region `reg`

```
reg = Annulus[{0, 0}, {2 Cosh[0], 2 Cosh[1] }]
Z = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[Div][ {Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y], 
       Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, y]}, {x, y}] + 
     Derivative[1, 0][z][x, 
       y] Inactive[Grad][Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, y], {x, y}] . 
       Inactive[
        Cross[{Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y], 
          Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, y]}]] - 
     Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, 
       y] Inactive[Grad][Derivative[1, 0  ][z][x, y], {x, y}] . 
       Inactive[
        Cross[{Derivative[1, 0  ][z][x, y], 
          Derivative[0, 1 ][z][x, y]}]] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[z[x, y] == 2, x^2 + y^2 == (2 Cosh[1])^2], 
   DirichletCondition[z[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == (2  Cosh[0])^2]}, z ,
   Element[{x, y}, reg]]

Plot3D[Z[x, y], Element[{x, y}, reg]]
```

[image]

I don't know why solution plot differs from your revolutionplot.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sadly, this answer is incorrect, because the equation hasn't been parsed properly by `NDSolve`, with [``NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225841/1871), we can check the equation being solved is actually `Inactive[Div][{Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y], Derivative[0, 1][z][x, y]}, {x, y}] == 0`

Comment: @xzczd Really sadly!!! How to apply `NDSolve\`FEM\`GetInactivePDE ` directly in v12.2? Or have I to use the subroutines from the `link`?

Comment: I just added a `checkFormalPDE` to make ``NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE`` easier to use: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280050/1871 Have a try :) .

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much, very helpful !

Comment: @xzczd Does it works for [my cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYrrt.png)?

Comment: @yode It doesn't, of course. The function only works for cases that the pre-processing has finished, in your case the pre-processer detects it cannot transform the equation to the required form and stops half-way.

Comment: @xzczd Is there any way to use MMA to change his variable `pde` into his `Div` forms? This looks like the key to solving this differential equation

Comment: @yode Very hard problem. (If it's that easy, it should have been part of `NDSolve` :) . ) So far I don't even see a MMA-aided method for the problem, such analyses always heavily depend on one's mental power. (Well, perhaps the method mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230282/3d-fem-vector-potential#comment682043_231131) can be considered as a MMA-aided method to some degree, but still, it's far beyond perfect. )