# Numeric Solution Hydrogen Atom

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics, eigenvalues

I'm trying to solve the Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom without made the variable separation of the polar and radial coordinate. It is my test code to extrapolate to another system with its polar symmetry broken. Explicitly, I wish to solve

$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}\left[\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial\psi(r,\theta)}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial\psi(r,\theta)}{\partial\theta}\right)-\frac{m^2}{r^2\sin^2\theta}\psi(r,\theta)\right]=E\psi(r,\theta)
$$

To do that, I use `NDEigensystem` as follows:

1. First, I define the Hamiltonian:

```
H=-(h^2/(2 me)) (1/r^2 D[r^2 D[y[r, t], r], r] + 
   1/(r^2 Sin[t])
     D[Sin[t] D[y[r, t], t], t] - 
   m^2/(r^2 Sin[t]^2) y[r, t])-((Z e^2)/(r))y[r,t];
```

2. Define my constants for the case $ m = 0 $

```
h = 1;
me = 1;
Z = 1;
e = 1;
m = 0;
a0 = (4 π ϵ0 h^2)/(m e^2);
```

3. I use the `NDEigensystem` routine. I add the term `S*y[r,t]`to ensure the correct eigenvalue ordering as was discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235662/ndeigensystem-and-radial-function-equation-for-hydrogen-atom/235691#235691).

```
S=10;
{valsHH, funsHH} = 
  NDEigensystem[{H+S*y[r,t]}, y[r,t], {r, 0, 100}, {t, 
    0,π}, 5, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}}];
```

4. The eigenvalues that I obtain are:

```
valsHH-S
{-0.500091, -0.125012, -0.125001, -0.0555551, -0.0550086}
```

Now, the correct eigenvalues should be

```
{-0.5, -0.125, -0.0555556, -0.03125, -0.02}
```

Do you know how to correct it?

**Edit 1: Degeneracy + Mesh + Upper limit of radial coordinate as possible solution**

I have analyzed the results and I found that the correct eigenvalues are indeed in the outputs. Nevertheless, there are other eigenvalues that are approximate to the analytic ones.

Also, I have added some boundary condition:

```
H=-(h^2/(2 me)) (1/r^2 D[r^2 D[y[r, t], r], r] + 
   1/(r^2 Sin[t])
     D[Sin[t] D[y[r, t], t], t] - 
   m^2/(r^2 Sin[t]^2) y[r, t])-((Z e^2)/(r))y[r,t];

h = 1;
me = 1;
Z = 1;
e = 1;
m = 0;
a0 = (4 π ϵ0 h^2)/(m e^2);
S=10;

{valsHH, funsHH} = 
  NDEigensystem[{H + S*y[r, t], 
    DirichletCondition[y[r, t] == 0., 
     r == 0 && 0 <= t <=Pi]}, y[r, t], {r, 0, 
    500}, {t, 0,Pi}, 6, 
   Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> \
{"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.005}}}}];

valsHH - S

Out[]= {-0.44711, -0.125, -0.118078, -0.0555375, -0.0534163, -0.0309502}
```

Now, I analyze the probability density.

```
G[n_] := DensityPlot[
   Abs[r*funsHH[[n]]]^2 /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] /. \[Theta] -> 
     ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]] , {x, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 80, 
   PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic];
GraphicsGrid[{Table[G[i], {i, 1, 3}], Table[G[i], {i, 4, 6}]}]
```

Obtaining:
[image: Probability Density]

Now, by comparing with the exact solution:

```
F[r_, t_, f_, n_, l_, m_] := 
  Abs[r*Sqrt[((2 Z)/(n a0))^3*(n - l - 1)!/(2 n ((n + l)!)^3)]
     Exp[-((Z r)/(n a0))] ((2 Z r)/(n a0))^
    l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, (2 Z r)/(
     n a0)] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, t, f]]^2;
```

```
GraphicsGrid[{{DensityPlot[
    F[Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]], ArcTan[0, x], 1, 0, 
     0] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
     PlotPoints -> 80, PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Exact: n=1, l=0, m=0", 15]], 
   DensityPlot[
    Abs[r*funsHH[[1]]]^2 /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] /. t -> 
      ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 80, 
    PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Numeric: n=1, m=0", 15]]}}, 
 Spacings -> {25, -50}]
```

[image: D2]

```
GraphicsGrid[{{DensityPlot[
    F[Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]], ArcTan[0, x], 2, 1, 
     0] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
     PlotPoints -> 80, PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Exact: n=1, l=1, m=0", 15]], 
   DensityPlot[
    Abs[r*funsHH[[2]]]^2 /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] /. t -> 
      ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 80, 
    PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Numeric: n=2, m=0", 15]]}}, 
 Spacings -> {25, -50}]
```

[image: D3]

```
GraphicsGrid[{{DensityPlot[
    F[Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]], ArcTan[0, x], 2, 0, 
     0] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
     PlotPoints -> 80, PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Exact: n=2, l=0, m=0", 15]], 
   DensityPlot[
    Abs[r*funsHH[[3]]]^2 /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] /. t -> 
      ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 80, 
    PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Numeric: n=2, m=0", 15]]}}, 
 Spacings -> {25, -50}]
```

[image: D5]

```
GraphicsGrid[{{DensityPlot[
    F[Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]], ArcTan[0, x], 3, 2, 
     0] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
     PlotPoints -> 80, PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Exact: n=3, l=2, m=0", 15]], 
   DensityPlot[
    Abs[r*funsHH[[4]]]^2 /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] /. t -> 
      ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 80, 
    PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Numeric: n=4, m=0", 15]]}}, 
 Spacings -> {25, -50}]
```

[image: D6]

```
GraphicsGrid[{{DensityPlot[
    F[Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]], ArcTan[0, x], 3, 0, 
     0] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
     PlotPoints -> 80, PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Exact: n=3, l=0, m=0", 15]], 
   DensityPlot[
    Abs[r*funsHH[[5]]]^2 /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] /. t -> 
      ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]] , {x, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 80, 
    PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Numeric: n=5, m=0", 15]]}}, 
 Spacings -> {25, -50}]
```

[image: D7]

```
GraphicsGrid[{{DensityPlot[
    F[Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]], ArcTan[0, x], 4, 1, 
     0] , {x, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
     PlotPoints -> 80, PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Exact: n=4,¿l=1?, m=0", 15]], 
   DensityPlot[
    Abs[r*funsHH[[6]]]^2 /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] /. t -> 
      ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2]] , {x, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 80, 
    PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Numeric: n=6, m=0", 15]]}}, 
 Spacings -> {25, -50}]
```

[image: D8]

From the above, maybe the code is giving the eigenvalues with different $l$ and same $m$. Also, by refining the mesh and a bigger $r_\text{max}$, it is possible to get better wave functions.

Comment: Are you just seeing the effect of degeneracies? When I try to run what you have there I get `1/0` error messages, but like obviously the hydrogen atom support many degenerate states. What do you get when you plot the wave functions?

Comment: Probably we can use the same trick as in my answer for this post  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199563/how-to-set-interface-conditions-for-optical-waveguide-in-ndeigensystem/199977#199977

Comment: `ϵ0` ? What is numeric value for this parameter ?

Comment: Hi @MariuszIwaniuk, ϵ0=1. I'm editing. Thanks.