# Manual updating of function in Do loop

Tags: differential-equations, physics

Previously I had asked a question about solving Maxwells equations with boundary conditions, here [Machine overflow when defining boundary conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291815/machine-overflow-when-defining-boundary-conditions).
I have managed to successfully run the code without problems since then.
However now I am trying to solve a system where the magnet is falling onto a conductor. It generates eddy current in the conductor through Maxwells equations. Then we have to do a triple integral across the whole conductor to find the magnetic field generated. After that, i have to do another integral of the magnetic field generated across the whole magnet.

I do not really have any code now as I am not sure where to start but it would look something like this

```
{
Maxwells equations,
bcs,
M {x''[t],y''[t],z''[t]} == Mg + Integrate[Integrate[currentfrom[xc,yc,zc,t],{xc,xmin,xmax},{yc,ymin,ymax}},{zc,zmin,zmax}], {rcylinder,rmin,rmax},{\[psi]cylinder,\[psi]min,\[psi]max},{zcylinder,zmin,zmax}]
}
```

The main issue with this is that the integrand will consist of a function that is solving simultaneously in the ndsolve and the integration will take very long due to the number of variables.

I possible solution I was thinking of was something like a manual timestep ie we run the code in a Do or For loop and we increment the time in each iteration. However, I foresee some problems with defining the numerical functions at the initial state as well as how to update the numerical functions (mainly the electric current functions).

I know this isn't much to go on about but I would really appreciate if someone could provide some guidance on how to go about solving this.